# How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

I set `dict2 = dict1`. When I edit `dict2`, the original `dict1` also changes. Why?

```
>>> dict1 = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
>>> dict2 = dict1
>>> dict2["key2"] = "WHY?!"
>>> dict1
{'key2': 'WHY?!', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Comment: [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com) is great for visualizing Python references. [Here's this code at the last step](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=dict1%20%3D%20%7B%22key1%22%3A%20%22value1%22,%20%22key2%22%3A%20%22value2%22%7D%0Adict2%20%3D%20dict1%0Adict2%5B%22key2%22%5D%20%3D%20%22WHY%3F!%22%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=3&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false). You can see `dict1` and `dict2` point to the same dict.

Comment: Just in case PythonTutor goes down, here's [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCekS.png) of the data structures at the end.

Answer (score 1419):

Python *never* implicitly copies objects. When you set `dict2 = dict1`, you are making them refer to the same exact dict object, so when you mutate it, all references to it keep referring to the object in its current state.

If you want to copy the dict (which is rare), you have to do so explicitly with

```
dict2 = dict(dict1)
```

or

```
dict2 = dict1.copy()
```

Comment: It might be better to say "dict2 and dict1 point to the **same** dictionary", you are not changing dict1 or dict2 but what they point to.

Comment: @GrayWizardx, I am not sure what you are suggesting. You think I should use the term "dictionary" instead of "dict object"?

Comment: No I was saying that its a pointer thing, but then I tried to rewrite it without sounding like a curmudgeony old C++ programmer telling people that new languages suck. Its a common problem for people learning c++ as well. Your answer is perfect as is, and I already +1'ed it.

Comment: Also note that the dict.copy() is shallow, if there is a nested list/etc in there changes will be applied to both. IIRC. Deepcopy will avoid that.

Comment: It is not quite correct that python never implicitly copies objects. Primitive data types, such as int, float, and bool, are also treated as objects (just do a `dir(1)` to see that), but they are implicitly copied.

Comment: @danielkullmann, I think you might have misunderstandings about Python based on how other languages you've dealt with work. In Python, a) There is no concept of "primitive data types". `int`, `float`, and `bool` instances are real Python objects, and b) objects of these types are not implicitly copied when you pass them, not at a semantic Python level for sure and not even as an implementation detail in CPython.

Comment: Another possibility: `dict2 = copy.copy(dict1)` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy))

Comment: I recommend doing your best to forget the `copy` module exists.

Comment: Note that using `dict1.copy()` will ensure your resulting type is the same as `dict1` when necessary. This may be important, e.g. when using `OrderedDict`

Comment: Use deepcopy if your dictionary is multiple layers deep and you want a completely independent copy... otherwise dcopy = d.copy(); dcopy['top']['nested']['bottom'] = 1 will change the object referred to by d['top']['nested']['bottom'] as well.  This burned me when trying to apply a range of offsets for a batch analysis to a value in a data structure inside a loop... my offsets were acting cumulatively because they were affecting the original as well as the copy.

Comment: Be **very** careful when you use `copy.deepcopy` -- it's very easy to introduce silent bugs. It can and should be avoided the vast majority of the time.

Comment: @MikeGraham could you mention why you say it is 'rare' to copy a dict?

Comment: @user1938107, More often you build a dict with the differences you want rather than copying the dict then mutating it.

Comment: @MikeGraham: Could you point to some examples of silent bugs from deepcopy? Something to do with sub-objects not copying properly?

Comment: So if I want to call a function that is not allowed to change the dict, I'd like to call `function(dict(myDict))`. But now changes in `function` to the input still apply to `myDict`. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What about a deep copy? What if I want to copy a dictionary of dictionaries? In that case, you would need `dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1)` from `import copy`

Comment: @MikeGraham: Same question as naught101: what bugs might arise from using deepcopy?

Comment: @MikeGraham: When you say more often you build a dict with the differences... So are you saying you use a dict that automatically links back to the original dict for fields that didn't change? Isn't it simpler to just copy the dict in such cases?

Comment: @naught101: It's very easy to accidentally copy too deep - there's often a point at which you want to stop copying. The cyclic reference handling is also kind of ad hoc and not as reliable as the docs would have you believe. One not-so-silent example is what happens if you try to deepcopy a [self-referential OrderedDict](https://ideone.com/PeX968) on Python 2.

Comment: @user2357112: haha... that looks like a well-deserved runtime error. I can't see how something like that would ever end well, or be a good idea to start with :P

Comment: @naught101: The thing is, `copy.deepcopy` *claims* it doesn't have problems with reference loops.

Comment: @user2357112: that code actually works fine on python 3.6.1... Still seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @naught101 I would also recommend to avoid deep-copying, not to avoid implementation errors in a library but to avoid design error in your own code. Copying is an expensive operation, and editing in-place or storing changes is often much faster (unless you really need fast access to the history of your object, but even then full copying is not necessary, see Redux). Another reason is that by copying you lose the single truth of source: all copies need to be updated for changes, and this can easily go inconsistent. As a rule of thumb, copy only if you can't control the code you share data with.

Comment: Unsubstantiated rhetoric like "Deep copy is considered harmful" is unhelpful. All else being equal, shallow copying a complex data structure is *significantly* more likely to yield unexpected edge case issues than deep copying the same structure. A copy in which modifications modify the original object isn't a copy; it's a bug. Ergo, most use cases absolutely *should* call `copy.deepcopy()` rather than `dict()` or `dict.copy()`. [Imran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1897/imran)'s [concise answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2465951/2809027) is on the right side of sanity, unlike this answer.

Comment: @CecilCurry: the proper answer is to understand how the Python object model works, of course. I recommend people read [Ned Batchelder's article on Python names](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), so they can make their own informed decision on what kind of copying they need. Sometimes the answer is not to copy at all, or to use a loop with shallow copying.

Comment: Both solutions didn't work for me, but `deep.copy()` worked

Comment: Usually you copy a dictionary in order to change it. In that case, both shallow copy methods fails, you need `dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1)`.

Comment: this answer is incorrect. The "deepcopy" answer is correct. Using a shallow copy is not a valid solution to the problem/question asked

Comment: @Hugo: It's a perfectly adequate solution for the OP's case, because both keys and values are immutable types; deep copying wouldn't improve it in any way (it won't even change the behavior; the "deep copy" of `str` is the identity function, it doesn't actually copy it, so shallow and deep copies are *identical* in end result here). I 100% agree that `deepcopy` is the safer solution when the values might be mutable types, but don't call this answer incorrect when it's 100% correct for the OP's specific use case.

Comment: The question is "How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy?" and shallow copy is not a correct answer. Shallow copy works for the example given in the question but that is just an edge case where the dict is flat. @MikeGraham should edit his answer.

Comment: This original answer based on the question asked is not just wrong, but dangerous. Say you had a module-level dictionary, effectively global, as a template that you want to modify in 1 or more functions when repeatedly called in different ways. As Cecil Curry and others say, a deep copy is the only way. After 11 years, I'd suggest this answer is taken down. There are also plenty of answers below that will still leave someone with a reference to the original dictionary when doing a supposed copy. If someone is in a hurry, they might not be reading these comments.

Answer (score 1204):

When you assign `dict2 = dict1`, you are not making a copy of `dict1`, it results in `dict2` being just another name for `dict1`.

To copy the mutable types like dictionaries, use `copy` / `deepcopy` of the [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module.

```
import copy

dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1)
```

Comment: For any dictionary I ever work with, deepcopy is what I need... I just lost several hours due to a bug that was because I wasn't getting a complete copy of a nested dictionary and my changes to nested entries were affecting the original.

Comment: This actually should be marked as the correct answer; This answer is general and it works for a dictionary of dictionaries as well.

Comment: **This should be the accepted answer.** The unsubstantiated "Deep copy is considered harmful" rhetoric embedded in the comment section of the current [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2465932/2809027) blatantly invites synchronization woes when copying nested dictionaries (such as those documented here) and should be challenged as such.

Comment: deepcopy is the way to go in case of a complex dictionary structure. dict1.copy() simply copies the values of keys as references and not as objects.

Comment: If you control the code using the dictionary, and the intent is that it, or any of the mutable objects it contains, not be altered, an appropriate code hint to warn developers would be useful (how?), or, use an "immutable" class that inhibits the normal means of modifying attributes (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711657/can-i-prevent-modifying-an-object-in-python). 

If the intent is for a dictionary to be a kind of template with the intent that it be mutated, then either deep copy, or a factory method return an object or dictionary of the right kind.

Answer (score 307):

While `dict.copy()` and `dict(dict1)` generates a copy, they are only *shallow* copies. If you want a *deep* copy, `copy.deepcopy(dict1)` is required. An example:

```
>>> source = {'a': 1, 'b': {'m': 4, 'n': 5, 'o': 6}, 'c': 3}
>>> copy1 = source.copy()
>>> copy2 = dict(source)
>>> import copy
>>> copy3 = copy.deepcopy(source)
>>> source['a'] = 10  # a change to first-level properties won't affect copies
>>> source
{'a': 10, 'c': 3, 'b': {'m': 4, 'o': 6, 'n': 5}}
>>> copy1
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': {'m': 4, 'o': 6, 'n': 5}}
>>> copy2
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': {'m': 4, 'o': 6, 'n': 5}}
>>> copy3
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': {'m': 4, 'o': 6, 'n': 5}}
>>> source['b']['m'] = 40  # a change to deep properties WILL affect shallow copies 'b.m' property
>>> source
{'a': 10, 'c': 3, 'b': {'m': 40, 'o': 6, 'n': 5}}
>>> copy1
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': {'m': 40, 'o': 6, 'n': 5}}
>>> copy2
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': {'m': 40, 'o': 6, 'n': 5}}
>>> copy3  # Deep copy's 'b.m' property is unaffected
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': {'m': 4, 'o': 6, 'n': 5}}
```

Regarding shallow vs deep copies, from the [Python `copy` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html):

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):

> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Comment: this should be the right answer as it doesn't to explicitly loop over the dict and can be used for other primary structures.

Comment: Just to clarify: `w=copy.deepcopy(x)` is the key line.

Comment: What is the difference between `dict2 = dict1` and `dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1)` ?

Comment: @TheTank, y=x makes the two names(references) refer to a same object, i.e. "y is x" is True. Any change made on the object through x is equivalent to a same change through y. However u, v, w are references to new different objects which have values copied from x during instantiation though. As for the differences between u,v(shallow copy) and w(deepcopy), please check https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 109):

**In Depth and an easy way to remember:**

Whenever you do `dict2 = dict1`, `dict2` refers to `dict1`. Both `dict1` and `dict2` point to the same location in the memory. This is just a normal case while working with mutable objects in Python. When you are working with mutable objects in Python you must be careful as it is hard to debug.

Instead of using `dict2 = dict1`, you should be using the **`copy`**(shallow copy) or **`deepcopy`** method from python's **copy module** to separate `dict2` from `dict1`.

#### The correct way to do this:

```py
>>> dict1 = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
>>> dict2 = dict1.copy()
>>> dict2
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> dict2["key2"] = "WHY?"
>>> dict2
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'WHY?'}
>>> dict1
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> id(dict1)
140641178056312
>>> id(dict2)
140641176198960
>>>
```

As you can see the **id** of both `dict1` and `dict2` are different, which means they are pointing to/referencing different locations in the memory.

This solution works for dictionaries with immutable values, but it is NOT the correct solution for those with mutable values.

#### Beware of mutables within your dictionary:

```py
>>> import copy
>>> dict1 = {"key1" : "value1", "key2": {"mutable": True}}
>>> dict2 = dict1.copy()
>>> dict2
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'mutable': True}}
>>> dict2["key2"]["mutable"] = False
>>> dict2
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'mutable': False}}
>>> dict1
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'mutable': False}}
>>> id(dict1)
140641197660704
>>> id(dict2)
140641196407832
>>> id(dict1["key2"])
140641176198960
>>> id(dict2["key2"])
140641176198960
```

You can see that even though we applied copy for `dict1`, the value of mutable is changed to false on both `dict2` and `dict1` even though we only change it on `dict2`. This is because we changed the value of a mutable dictionary part of `dict1`. When we do a `.copy()` on dictionary, by default, it will only do a **shallow copy**, which means it copies all the immutable values into a new dictionary but **does not copy the mutable values**, only reference them.

The ultimate solution is to do a `.deepycopy()` of `dict1` to create a completely a new and separate dictionary with everything inside it copied, *including* mutable values.

```py
>>>import copy
>>> dict1 = {"key1" : "value1", "key2": {"mutable": True}}
>>> dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1)
>>> dict2
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'mutable': True}}
>>> id(dict1)
140641196228824
>>> id(dict2)
140641197662072
>>> id(dict1["key2"])
140641178056312
>>> id(dict2["key2"])
140641197662000
>>> dict2["key2"]["mutable"] = False
>>> dict2
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'mutable': False}}
>>> dict1
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': {'mutable': True}}
```

As you can see the id's are different, which means that `dict2` is a completely new dictionary containing merely copies of the items from `dict1`.

Deepcopy must be used whenever you want to change any of the mutable values without affecting the original dictionary. If not you can use shallow copy. Deepcopy is slow as it works recursively to copy any nested values in the original dictionary and also takes extra memory.

Answer (score 83):

On python 3.5+ there is an easier way to achieve a shallow copy by using the ** unpackaging operator. Defined by [Pep 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

```
>>>dict1 = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
>>>dict2 = {**dict1}
>>>print(dict2)
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>>dict2["key2"] = "WHY?!"
>>>print(dict1)
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>>print(dict2)
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'WHY?!'}
```

** unpackages the dictionary into a new dictionary that is then assigned to dict2.

We can also confirm that each dictionary has a distinct id.

```
>>>id(dict1)
 178192816

>>>id(dict2)
 178192600
```

If a deep copy is needed then [copy.deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) is still the way to go.

Comment: This looks awfully like pointers in C++. Nice for accomplishing the task, but readability wise I tend to dislike this type of operators.

Comment: It does have a kind of c'ish look... but when merging together multiple dictionaries, the syntax does look pretty smooth.

Comment: Be careful with that, it performs only a shallow copy.

Comment: you are right @SebastianDressler, i'll makde adjustments. thnx.

Comment: Usefull if you want create copy with some spicies: `dict2 = {**dict1, 'key3':'value3'}`

Comment: @evg656e very true. Although out of the scope for this particular question.

Comment: Be careful if your value is e.g a list, then this wont work and will effectively have the same limitation as this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40927862/5506988

Comment: OP wants deep copy: "only edit the copy".

Answer (score 55):

The best and the easiest ways to *create a copy* of a **dict** in both **Python 2.7 and 3** are...

**To create a copy of simple(single-level) dictionary:**

**1.** Using **dict()** method, instead of generating a reference that points to the existing dict.

```
my_dict1 = dict()
my_dict1["message"] = "Hello Python"
print(my_dict1)  # {'message':'Hello Python'}

my_dict2 = dict(my_dict1)
print(my_dict2)  # {'message':'Hello Python'}

# Made changes in my_dict1 
my_dict1["name"] = "Emrit"
print(my_dict1)  # {'message':'Hello Python', 'name' : 'Emrit'}
print(my_dict2)  # {'message':'Hello Python'}
```

**2.** Using the built-in **update()** method of python dictionary.

```
my_dict2 = dict()
my_dict2.update(my_dict1)
print(my_dict2)  # {'message':'Hello Python'}

# Made changes in my_dict1 
my_dict1["name"] = "Emrit"
print(my_dict1)  # {'message':'Hello Python', 'name' : 'Emrit'}
print(my_dict2)  # {'message':'Hello Python'}
```

**To create a copy of nested or complex dictionary:**

Use the built-in **copy** module, which provides a generic shallow and deep copy operations. This module is present in both Python 2.7 and 3.*

```
import copy

my_dict2 = copy.deepcopy(my_dict1)
```

Comment: I believe `dict()` creates a shallow copy not a deep copy. Meaning that if you have a nested `dict` then the outer `dict` will be a copy but the inner dict will be a reference to the original inner dict.

Comment: @shmuels  yes, both of these methods will create a shallow copy, not the deep one. See, the updated answer.

Answer (score 41):

You can also just make a new dictionary with a dictionary comprehension.  This avoids importing copy.

```
dout = dict((k,v) for k,v in mydict.items())
```

Of course in python >= 2.7 you can do:

```
dout = {k:v for k,v in mydict.items()}
```

But for backwards compat., the top method is better.

Comment: This is particularly useful if you want more control over how and what exactly is copied. +1

Comment: Note that this method does not perform a deep copy, and if you want a shallow copy with no need to control over keys to be copied, `d2 = dict.copy(d1)` doesn't require any imports either.

Comment: @JarekPiórkowski: or you can call a method like a method: `d2 = d1.copy()`

Comment: Note that you don't need the comprehension in the first example. `dict.items` already returns a key/value pair iterable. So you can just use `dict(mydict.items())` (you can also just use `dict(mydict)`). It may be useful to have the comprehension if you wanted to filter the entries.

Answer (score 35):

In addition to the other provided solutions, you can use `**` to integrate the dictionary into an empty dictionary, e.g.,

**`shallow_copy_of_other_dict = {**other_dict}`**.

Now you will have a "shallow" copy of `other_dict`.

Applied to your example:

```
>>> dict1 = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
>>> dict2 = {**dict1}
>>> dict2
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> dict2["key2"] = "WHY?!"
>>> dict1
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>>
```

[Pointer: Difference between shallow and deep copys](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html)

Comment: This results in a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Comment: I was trying this but having trouble.  This only works for python 3.5 and up. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Answer (score 22):

Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object.

so, `dict2 = dict1`, it results another binding between `dict2`and the object that `dict1` refer to.

if you want to copy a dict, you can use the `copy module`.
The copy module has two interface:

```
copy.copy(x)
Return a shallow copy of x.

copy.deepcopy(x)
Return a deep copy of x.
```

The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):

A ***shallow copy*** constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.

A ***deep copy*** constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

For example, in python 2.7.9:

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,['a', 'b']]
>>> b = a
>>> c = copy.copy(a)
>>> d = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> a.append(5)
>>> a[4].append('c')
```

and the result is:

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 5]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 5]
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 4, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
>>> d
[1, 2, 3, 4, ['a', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 15):

You can copy and edit the newly constructed copy in one go by calling the `dict` constructor with additional keyword arguments:

```
>>> dict1 = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
>>> dict2 = dict(dict1, key2="WHY?!")
>>> dict1
{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
>>> dict2
{'key2': 'WHY?!', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Comment: The only oneliner answer that allow immutable add to a dict

Answer (score 12):

This confused me too, initially, because I was coming from a C background.

In C, a variable is a location in memory with a defined type. Assigning to a variable copies the data into the variable's memory location.

But in Python, variables act more like pointers to objects. So assigning one variable to another doesn't make a copy, it just makes that variable name point to the same object.

Comment: python variables act more like c++ references

Comment: Because everything in Python is an object!  
http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html

(yes, this response is many years late, but perhaps it's of some use to someone!)

Comment: I believe that Python language semantics say there are no "variables". They are called "named references"; meaning the reference to an object is a syntactic string in code. An object can have many named references to it. Immutable objects like ints and floats and str instances have only one instance of it per process. An int of 1 in memory does not change to a 2 or some other value at the same memory address when you do this myvalue=1   myvalue=2

Answer (score 11):

`dict1` is a symbol that references an underlying dictionary object. Assigning `dict1` to `dict2` merely assigns the same reference. Changing a key's value via the `dict2` symbol changes the underlying object, which also affects `dict1`. This is confusing.

It is far easier to reason about immutable values than references, so make copies whenever possible:

```
person = {'name': 'Mary', 'age': 25}
one_year_later = {**person, 'age': 26}  # does not mutate person dict
```

This is syntactically the same as:

```
one_year_later = dict(person, age=26)
```

Answer (score 8):

Every variable in python (stuff like `dict1` or `str` or `__builtins__` is a pointer to some hidden platonic "object" inside the machine.

If you set `dict1 = dict2`,you just point `dict1` to the same object (or memory location, or whatever analogy you like) as `dict2`. Now, the object referenced by `dict1` is the same object referenced by `dict2`.

You can check: `dict1 is dict2` should be `True`. Also, `id(dict1)` should be the same as `id(dict2)`.

You want `dict1 = copy(dict2)`, or `dict1 = deepcopy(dict2)`.

The difference between `copy` and `deepcopy`? `deepcopy` will make sure that the elements of `dict2` (did you point it at a list?) are also copies.

I don't use `deepcopy` much - it's usually poor practice to write code that needs it (in my opinion).

Comment: I just realized I need to always be using deepcopy so that when I copy a nested dictionary and start modifying nested entries, the effects occur only on the copy and not the original.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> dict2 = dict1
# dict2 is bind to the same Dict object which binds to dict1, so if you modify dict2, you will modify the dict1
```

There are many ways to copy Dict object, I simply use

```
dict_1 = {
           'a':1,
           'b':2
         }
dict_2 = {}
dict_2.update(dict_1)
```

Comment: `dict_2 = dict_1.copy()` is much more efficient and logical.

Comment: Note that if you have a dict inside dict1, with dict_1.copy() the changes you do on the inner dict in dict_2 are also applied to the inner dict in dict_1. In this case you should use copy.deepcopy(dict_1) instead.

Answer (score 6):

`dict2 = dict1` does not copy the dictionary. It simply gives you the programmer a second way (`dict2`) to refer to the same dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

the following code, which is on dicts which follows json syntax more than 3 times faster than deepcopy

```
def CopyDict(dSrc):
    try:
        return json.loads(json.dumps(dSrc))
    except Exception as e:
        Logger.warning("Can't copy dict the preferred way:"+str(dSrc))
        return deepcopy(dSrc)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained, the built-in `dict` does not do what you want. But in Python2 (and probably 3 too) you can easily create a `ValueDict` class that copies with `=` so you can be sure that the original will not change.

```
class ValueDict(dict):

    def __ilshift__(self, args):
        result = ValueDict(self)
        if isinstance(args, dict):
            dict.update(result, args)
        else:
            dict.__setitem__(result, *args)
        return result # Pythonic LVALUE modification

    def __irshift__(self, args):
        result = ValueDict(self)
        dict.__delitem__(result, args)
        return result # Pythonic LVALUE modification

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        raise AttributeError, \
            "Use \"value_dict<<='%s', ...\" instead of \"d[%s] = ...\"" % (k,k)

    def __delitem__(self, k):
        raise AttributeError, \
            "Use \"value_dict>>='%s'\" instead of \"del d[%s]" % (k,k)

    def update(self, d2):
        raise AttributeError, \
            "Use \"value_dict<<=dict2\" instead of \"value_dict.update(dict2)\""


# test
d = ValueDict()

d <<='apples', 5
d <<='pears', 8
print "d =", d

e = d
e <<='bananas', 1
print "e =", e
print "d =", d

d >>='pears'
print "d =", d
d <<={'blueberries': 2, 'watermelons': 315}
print "d =", d
print "e =", e
print "e['bananas'] =", e['bananas']


# result
d = {'apples': 5, 'pears': 8}
e = {'apples': 5, 'pears': 8, 'bananas': 1}
d = {'apples': 5, 'pears': 8}
d = {'apples': 5}
d = {'watermelons': 315, 'blueberries': 2, 'apples': 5}
e = {'apples': 5, 'pears': 8, 'bananas': 1}
e['bananas'] = 1

# e[0]=3
# would give:
# AttributeError: Use "value_dict<<='0', ..." instead of "d[0] = ..."
```

Please refer to the lvalue modification pattern discussed here: [Python 2.7 - clean syntax for lvalue modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788271/python-2-7-clean-syntax-for-lvalue-modification). The key observation is that `str` and `int` behave as values in Python (even though they're actually immutable objects under the hood). While you're observing that, please also observe that nothing is magically special about `str` or `int`. `dict` can be used in much the same ways, and I can think of many cases where `ValueDict` makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

for nested dictionay do not use `dict(srcData) or srcData.copy() or {**srcData}` because if you change second level and more it will also modify source dictionary

```
srcData = {
  'first': {
    'second': 'second Value'
  }
}
newData = dict(srcData) # srcData.copy() or {**srcData}
newData['first']['second'] = 'new Second Value'

print(srcData)
print(newData)

# it will print
# srcData: {'first': {'second': 'new Second Value'}}
# newData:{'first': {'second': 'new Second Value'}}

# but it should be
# srcData: {'first': {'second': 'second Value'}}
# newData:{'first': {'second': 'new Second Value'}}
```

another option for deepcopy is using `json` trick like Javascript `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

```
import json

srcData = {'first': {'second': 'second Value'}}
newData = json.loads(json.dumps(srcData))
newData['first']['second'] = 'new Second Value'

print(srcData)
print(newData)

# srcData: {'first': {'second': 'second Value'}}
# newData: {'first': {'second': 'new Second Value'}}
```

Comment: json has no benefit over deepcopy, has greater overhead and many things are not json-serializable

Answer (score 0):

i ran into a peculiar behavior when trying to deep copy dictionary property of class w/o assigning it to variable

`new = copy.deepcopy(my_class.a)` doesn't work i.e. modifying `new` modifies `my_class.a`

but if you do `old = my_class.a` and then `new = copy.deepcopy(old)` it works perfectly i.e. modifying `new` does not affect `my_class.a`

I am not sure why this happens, but hope it helps save some hours! :)

Comment: So how do you make a deepcopy of `my_class.a`?

Comment: Not the best way. Good response is bellow.

Answer (score -4):

Copying by using a for loop:

```
orig = {"X2": 674.5, "X3": 245.0}

copy = {}
for key in orig:
    copy[key] = orig[key]

print(orig) # {'X2': 674.5, 'X3': 245.0}
print(copy) # {'X2': 674.5, 'X3': 245.0}
copy["X2"] = 808
print(orig) # {'X2': 674.5, 'X3': 245.0}
print(copy) # {'X2': 808, 'X3': 245.0}
```

Comment: This only works for simple dictionaries. Why not use `deepcopy`, which is built expressly for this purpose?

Comment: Not the best way. Good response is bellow.

Comment: somehow none of the "copies" worked for me. Only this way it works. Another better way to write this would be using dictionary comprehension; like this:
 `def _copy_dict(dictionary:dict):
    return {key: dictionary[key] for key in dictionary}`

Answer (score -7):

You can use directly:

```
dict2 = eval(repr(dict1))
```

where object dict2 is an independent copy of dict1, so you can modify dict2 without affecting dict1.

This works for any kind of object.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, and should not be used.  A user-defined class, for example, may not have an appropriate `__repr__` to be reconstructed by eval, nor may the object's class be in the current scope to be called.  Even sticking with built-in types, this will fail if the same object is stored under multiple keys, as `dict2` would then have two separate objects.  A self-referential dictionary, where `dict1` contains itself, will instead contain `Ellipsis`.

It would be better to use `dict1.copy()`

Comment: Objects (or "values") are not expected to always have a faithful representation by character strings, not in a usual human readable way in any case.

Answer (score -8):

Another cleaner way would be using json. see below code

```
>>> a = [{"name":"Onkar","Address": {"state":"MH","country":"India","innerAddress":{"city":"Pune"}}}]
>>> b = json.dumps(a)
>>> b = json.loads(b)
>>> id(a)
2334461105416
>>> id(b)
2334461105224
>>> a[0]["Address"]["innerAddress"]["city"]="Nagpur"
>>> a
[{'name': 'Onkar', 'Address': {'state': 'MH', 'country': 'India', 'innerAddress': {'city': 'Nagpur'}}}]
>>> b
[{'name': 'Onkar', 'Address': {'state': 'MH', 'country': 'India', 'innerAddress': {'city': 'Pune'}}}]
>>> id(a[0]["Address"]["innerAddress"])
2334460618376
>>> id(b[0]["Address"]["innerAddress"])
2334424569880
```

To create another dictionary do json.dumps() and then json.loads() on the same dictionary object. You will have separate dict object.

Comment: This only works for json-serializable entries and incurs a great overhead.