# Create constants using a "settings" module?

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python. I am looking to create a "settings" module where various application-specific constants will be stored.

Here is how I am wanting to set up my code:

settings.py

```
CONSTANT = 'value'
```

script.py

```
import settings

def func():
    var = CONSTANT
    # do some more coding
    return var
```

I am getting a Python error stating:

> `global name 'CONSTANT' is not defined.`

I have noticed on Django's source code their `settings.py` file has constants named just like I do. I am confused on how they can be imported to a script and referenced through the application.

**EDIT**

Thank you for all your answers! I tried the following:

```
import settings

print settings.CONSTANT
```

I get the same error

> `ImportError: cannot import name CONSTANT`

Comment: That makes not sense. you should be getting an `AttributeError` if `settings` doesn't define `CONSTANT` and an `ImportError` if it can't import settings, in which case it wouldn't even look at `CONSTANT`

Comment: Is there something I am doing wrong then?

Comment: Put the two lines that you posted last in a file by it self exactly as you posted them and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your help. I figured it out. It had to do with the placement of the __init__.py file. I was trying to import settings so python was looking couldn't find it so once I referenced the "modules" directory settings was in, everything worked properly. So basically my import statement looks like this: from modules import settings. I think there is a better way to do this, a more pythonic, so I am going to try different combinations. Again thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just have settings be a module.

(settings.py)

```
CONSTANT1 = "value1"
CONSTANT2 = "value2"
```

(consumer.py)

```
import settings

print settings.CONSTANT1
print settings.CONSTANT2
```

When you import a python module, you have to prefix the the variables that you pull from it with the module name. If you know exactly what values you want to use from it in a given file **and** you are not worried about them changing during execution, then you can do

```
from settings import CONSTANT1, CONSTANT2

print CONSTANT1
print CONSTANT2
```

but I wouldn't get carried away with that last one. It makes it difficult for people reading your code to tell where values are coming from. and precludes those values being updated if another client module changes them. One final way to do it is

```
import settings as s

print s.CONSTANT1
print s.CONSTANT2
```

This saves you typing, will propagate updates and only requires readers to remember that anything after `s` is from the settings module.

Comment: @delnan I specifically avoided mentioning the mechanics so as to not make your answer obsolete ;)

Comment: Well, practically obsolete ;) Knowing the exact semantics is useful and preferable, but to make it work, it's not needed - though it is necessary to know the implications of it, which are pretty much summarzied in your answer.

Comment: I though the idea of constant is that it cannot be changed on runtime?

Comment: @Lie Ryan, Python doesn't have constants. On multiprogrammer projects, you never know.

Comment: @AaronMcSmoot: yes, but if you even have the intention to change a constant after runtime, that's very suspect that you've got the wrong design.

Comment: @Lie Ryan. I'm not sure that I entirely agree. 'setting' is a more accurate term than 'constant' in python and why can't settings change so long as all client code is aware of it? Regardless though, the fact that it's a possibility means that it should be taken into account

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: settings != CONSTANTS. Changing constants at runtime does not make sense. IMO, if you take into account the possibility of changing a constant, then you're overdesigning. OTOH, settings are meant to be changed on runtime; but settings shouldn't use ALLCAPS, otherwise you're nullifying the advantage of having constants written in ALLCAPS.

Comment: @Lie Ryan. about the overdesign. When the only thing that i'm advocating is that those changes (if they occur) propagate, then I don't think that's overdesign. Especially not if it dovetails with what is otherwise a best practive, such as avoiding barenames. It makes mocking for tests easier, for instance.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: what I'm trying to say is, that those changes should not happen at all. If there is a change in the value of a constant, then it's a bug; either in the design or in the program itself. Why would you want to have a different constant values when testing? They should never change, period. You should never assign to an ALLCAPS name, except once when declaring the constant. There is no need to design it for the possibility of changing it.

Answer (score 18):

> **step 1: create a new file settings.py on the same directory for easier access.**

```
#database configuration settings

database = dict(
    DATABASE = "mysql",
    USER     = "Lark",
    PASS     = ""
)

#application predefined constants

app = dict(
    VERSION   = 1.0,
    GITHUB    = "{url}"
)
```

> **step 2: importing settings module into your application file.**

```
import settings as s            # s is aliasing settings & settings is the actual file you do not have to add .py 

print(s.database['DATABASE'])   # should output mysql

print(s.app['VERSION'])         # should output 1.0
```

if you do not like to use alias like s you can use a **different syntax**

```
from settings import database, app

print(database['DATABASE'])   # should output mysql

print(app['VERSION'])         # should output 1.0
```

**notice on the second import method you can use the dict names directly**

**A small tip** you can **import all** the code on the **settings file** by using * in case you have a large file and you will be using most of the settings on it on your application

```
from settings import *      # * represent all the code on the file, it will work like step 2


print(database['USER'])       # should output lark

print(app['VERSION'])         # should output 1.0
```

i hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

When you `import settings`, a `module` object called `settings` is placed in the global namespace - and this object carries has that was in `settings.py` as attributes. I.e. outside of `settings.py`, you refer to `CONSTANT` as `settings.CONSTANT`.

Answer (score 4):

Leave your settings.py exactly as it is, then you can use it just as Django does:

```
import settings

def func():
    var = settings.CONSTANT
```

Answer (score 3):

...Or, if you *really* want all the constants from settings.py to be imported into the global namespace, you can run

```
from settings import *
```

...but otherwise using `settings.CONSTANT`, as everyone else has mentioned here, is quite right.

Comment: See my answer for all three possible ways to use the `import` statement.

Comment: Actually, this is not advisable. See e.g. http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import. Although in this case it has the propably desirable side effect that changes to the constants won't affect other modules.

Comment: Nicely said, @AaronMcSmooth. And technically I didn't say it was advisable to import *, just that it was possible :P

Comment: @delnan. I'm not so sure that that's desirable. It depends on the application but It could just as likely be that changes should be propagated (if they even occur)

Answer (score 3):

See the answer I posted to [Can I prevent modifying an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711657/can-i-prevent-modifying-an-object-in-python/3712574#3712574) which does what you want (as well as force the use of UPPERCASE identifiers). It might actually be a better answer for this question than it was for the the other.

Answer (score 3):

This way is more efficient since it loads/evaluates your settings variables only once. It works well for all my Python projects.

```
pip install python-settings
```

Docs here: https://github.com/charlsagente/python-settings

You need a settings.py file with all your defined constants like:

```
# settings.py

DATABASE_HOST = '10.0.0.1'
```

Then you need to either set an env variable (export SETTINGS_MODULE=settings) or manually calling the configure method:

```
# something_else.py

from python_settings import settings
from . import settings as my_local_settings

settings.configure(my_local_settings) # configure() receives a python module
```

The utility also supports Lazy initialization for heavy to load objects, so when you run your python project it loads faster since it only evaluates the settings variable when its needed

```
# settings.py

from python_settings import LazySetting
from my_awesome_library import HeavyInitializationClass # Heavy to initialize object

LAZY_INITIALIZATION = LazySetting(HeavyInitializationClass, "127.0.0.1:4222") 
# LazySetting(Class, *args, **kwargs)
```

Just configure once and now call your variables where is needed:

```
# my_awesome_file.py

from python_settings import settings 

print(settings.DATABASE_HOST) # Will print '10.0.0.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm new in python but if we define an constant like a function
on setings.py

```
def CONST1():
    return "some value"
```

main.py

```
import setings

print setings.CONST1() ##take an constant value
```

here I see only one, value cant be changed but its work like a function..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In settings.py:

```
CONSTANT = 5
```

In your main file:

```
from settings import CONSTANT

class A:
    b = CONSTANT

    def printb(self):
         print self.b
```

I think your above error is coming from the settings file being imported too late. Make sure it's at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth checking out is the [simple-settings](https://github.com/drgarcia1986/simple-settings) project which allows you to feed the settings into your script at runtim, which allows for environment-specific settings (think dev, test, prod,...)