# Importing a long list of constants to a Python file

Tags: python, constants, python-import

In Python, is there an analogue of the `C` preprocessor statement such as?:

`#define MY_CONSTANT 50`

Also, I have a large list of constants I'd like to import to several classes. Is there an analogue of declaring the constants as a long sequence of statements like the above in a `.py` file and importing it to another `.py` file?

Edit.

The file `Constants.py` reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
Constants.py
"""

MY_CONSTANT_ONE = 50
MY_CONSTANT_TWO = 51
```

And `myExample.py` reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
myExample.py
"""

import sys
import os

import Constants

class myExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.someValueOne = Constants.MY_CONSTANT_ONE + 1
        self.someValueTwo = Constants.MY_CONSTANT_TWO + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = MyClass()
```

Edit.

From the compiler,

> NameError: "global name
>   'MY_CONSTANT_ONE' is not defined"
>
> function **init** in myExample at line
>   13 self.someValueOne =
>   Constants.MY_CONSTANT_ONE + 1 copy
>   output Program exited with code #1
>   after 0.06 seconds.

Comment: No, there is no preprocessor. And no, you won't get very far trying to code C in Python, or even trying to find parallels.

Comment: That's not the full traceback. How you're running it? `python myExample.py` should give a traceback on error that includes file names and `<module>` as top level. Plus, `MY_CONSTANT_ONE` **isn't** references as a global name - really weird. Triple-check that those are really the files you're running (and perhaps convert them to ASCII and strip the `# encoding: utf8` bit).

Comment: @All: Thanks, I seem to be fine now - not yet sure why, but never mind :).

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Python isn't preprocessed. You can just create a file `myconstants.py`:

```
MY_CONSTANT = 50
```

And importing them will just work:

```
import myconstants
print myconstants.MY_CONSTANT * 2
```

Comment: @SK9: Well, show the exact code you're running (both defining and using module).

Comment: @Thomas: See above. I've definitely missed something daft some where as I'm learning the basics.

Comment: @SK9: There is no such error in the code you posted. I checked it several times and run it myself, it works just fine. It **can't** even lead to this error (there's no reference to a name `MAX_FIVE_FLUSH_KEY_INT`). Post the traceback.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for testing this. Hmm, I'll try again. (The reference alluded to is a typo.) You tried the files literally as is? (I copied and pasted the full contents above.)

Comment: @SK9: I'm not Thomas ;) And yes, I copied and pasted everything, I even left the filenames as they are. Again, the traceback would help us debugging.

Comment: @delnan: Thanks ;) What I have from the log is now posted above.

Comment: @SK9: you have a file called myConstants.py, but you import the module Constants?  If you didn't get an ImportError, you either have multiple versions of files around or you're not posting what you actually ran.

Comment: @DSM: The docstring of the file itself says `Constants.py` though. And even if that was the case, that still wouldn't explain why and how it thinks the `MY_CONSTANT_ONE` in `Constants.MY_CONSTANT_ONE` was a global name.

Comment: @DSM: Yes it should be "Constants.py" (I have that in my code etc.) so that's not it. Hmm.

Comment: @delnan: docstrings don't change the module name, and I was wondering if it was a different version of the code which was being imported, which might be doing something weird.  I can't explain the error message, though.

Comment: Okay, this is insane, but is it possible that periods and commas have been swapped somehow?  This is exactly the error message you'd get if that were true!

Comment: @delnan, @DSM : Thanks for fielding on this one. I have my browser block SO during working hours, to discourage procrastination.

Comment: Be sure not to use '-' in module names. Use '_' instead - causes issues with thing like `from <module name> import const`

Answer (score 25):

Python doesn't have a preprocessor, nor does it have constants in the sense that they can't be changed - you can always change (nearly, you can emulate constant object properties, but doing this for the sake of constant-ness is rarely done and not considered useful) everything. When defining a constant, we define a name that's upper-case-with-underscores and call it a day - "We're all consenting adults here", no sane man would change a constant. Unless of course he has very good reasons and knows exactly what he's doing, in which case you can't (and propably shouldn't) stop him either way.

But of course you can define a module-level name with a value and use it in another module. This isn't specific to constants or anything, read up on the module system.

```
# a.py
MY_CONSTANT = ...

# b.py
import a
print a.MY_CONSTANT
```

Answer (score 17):

And ofcourse you can do:

```
# a.py
MY_CONSTANT = ...

# b.py
from a import *
print MY_CONSTANT
```

Comment: [`import *` is of the devil.](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import)

Comment: import * is discouraged in general, but C-style manifest constants that are widely used across a codebase are one of the places where it's not insane to use it. Naming them in ALL_CAPS or with some prefix convention that reduces the possibility of collision with other symbols removes the main objection to the idiom, and if a collision does occur you can always fall back to the conventional import + explicit name style (import a; a.MY_CONSTNAT), unlike in C.

Comment: also a.MY_CONSTNAT a little slower, that's because interpreter looking in one namespace for name 'a' and then in second one foe name 'MY_CONSTNAT'

Comment: I personally use `import *` a lot, and it werks out well enough.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, you can put your constants into a separate module. For example:

const.py:

```
A = 12
B = 'abc'
C = 1.2
```

main.py:

```
import const

print const.A, const.B, const.C
```

Note that as declared above, `A`, `B` and `C` are variables, i.e. can be changed at run time.

Answer (score 7):

Try to look [Create constants using a "settings" module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824455/python-constants) and [Can I prevent modifying an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711657/can-i-prevent-modifying-an-object-in-python)

Another one useful link: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/ tells us about the following option:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class const(object):

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self.__dict__.has_key(name):
            print 'NO WAY this is a const' # put here anything you want(throw exc and etc)
            return deepcopy(self.__dict__[name])
        self.__dict__[name] = value

    def __getattr__(self, name, value):
        if self.__dict__.has_key(name):
            return deepcopy(self.__dict__[name])

    def __delattr__(self, item):
        if self.__dict__.has_key(item):
            print 'NOOOOO' # throw exception if needed

CONST = const()
CONST.Constant1 = 111
CONST.Constant1 = 12
print a.Constant1 # 111
CONST.Constant2 = 'tst'
CONST.Constant2 = 'tst1'
print a.Constant2 # 'tst'
```

So you could create a class like this and then import it from you contants.py module. This will allow you to be sure that value would not be changed, deleted.

Comment: Thanks for this. Before asking on SO I searched and found both of these. :)

Comment: @SK9 oh, sorry for duplicate then

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to using the import approach described in several answers, have a look a the [configparser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#module-ConfigParser) module.

The ConfigParser class implements a basic configuration file parser language which provides a structure similar to what you would find on Microsoft Windows INI files. You can use this to write Python programs which can be customized by end users easily.

Answer (score 4):

create constant file with any name like my_constants.py
declare constant like that

```
CONSTANT_NAME = "SOME VALUE"
```

For accessing constant in your code import file like that

```
import my_constants as constant
```

and access the constant value as -

```
constant.CONSTANT_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want constants, not just variables looking like constants, the standard way to do it is to use immutable dictionaries. Unfortunately it's not built-in yet, so you have to use third party recipes (like [this one](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/414283/) or [that one](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498072-implementing-an-immutable-dictionary/)).

Answer (score 0):

In commercial software, the constant(s) will frequently be buried many folders deep. Use solution below in combination with above solutions for best results.  Here's the syntax that worked for me:

```
folder_a
    folder_b
        constants.py
# -----------
# constants.py
# ------------
MAXVAL = 1000

folder_c
    folder_d
        my_file.py

# ------------------------
# my_file.py
# ------------------------
import folder_a.folder_b.constants as consts

print(consts.MAXVAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

In more recent editions, it seems a bit pickier.

the mode in the top answer

**Main.py**

```
import constants
print(token)
```

**constants.py**
`enter code here`token = "12345"

failed.
Instead, I had to import individual variable from constants.

**Main.py**

```
from constants import token
print(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `constants.py` file is good, but I ran into a situation where I would rather had my constants on top of the file.

A similar Python dict would need an access to the variable with a string key `dict['A']`, but I needed something with the same syntax as a module import.

(For the curious, I was working on Google Collab `.ipynb` multiple files, with different configuration variables for each of them, and you can't edit quickly an imported `constants.py` from Collab, nor import directly another `.ipynb` file. )

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Constants:
    A = "foo"

cst = Constants()
print(cst.A)
>>> "foo"
```

You could also create a classic Python `Class`, but this needs to define a `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

## This is my solution:

##### Asum Directory structure

```
project
|-- package1
|   |-- param1.py
|
|-- package2
|   |-- somefile.py
|
|-- main.py
|-- param2.py
```

##### param1.py

```
MY_CONST = 'abc'
```

##### param2.py

```
MY_CONST = 'xyz'
```

##### somefile.py

```
from package1 import param1

my_var = "inside some file " + param1.MY_CONST
```

##### main.py

```
from package1 import param1
import param2
from package2 import somefile

print(param1.MY_CONST)
print(param2.MY_CONST)
print(somefile.my_var)
```

### Run main.py

##### Result:

```
abc
xyz
inside some file abc
```

As you can see, you can use const from another package.
Hope this helps others!!