# python initialization of constants in separate file

Tags: python, class, import, constants

I have a question similar to the question asked here: [Importing a long list of constants to a Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343330/importing-a-long-list-of-constants-to-a-python-file)

Basically, I have a separate module which just contains a long list of constants, e.g.

```
constants.py

x = 1.2
y = 30.4
.
.
.
```

In another module, I would like import these constants and initialize them as instance attributes.

```
class.py

class something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        import constants
        self.x = constants.x
        self.y = constants.y
        .
        .
        .
```

Is there an easier or more pythonic way to do this instead of retyping all of the variable names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python developers have developed a cool solution: it's called [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html).

A practical example: config.ini

```
[constants]
key = value
x = 0
y = 1
```

class.py

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.config = SafeConfigParser(defaults=kwargs).read('config.ini')

    def get_x(self):
        return self.config.get('constants', 'x')
```

I hope this helps.

EDIT: If you need instance attributes, you can do:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.config.get('constants', key)
```

EDIT2: need a Python file and a .ini file is not a solution?

```
from . import config
class Myclass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(config, key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
for constant, value in constants.__dict__.values():
  setattr(self, constant, value)
```

Why do you need them as instance attributes?

Comment: Thanks. Just for the syntax to access them: "instance.attribute"

Answer (score 1):

You could put the constants in a class in the module. This class can be more easily passed around, or used as a mixin class for any class that needs those constants as class attributes.

```
class Constants(object):
    x = 1.2
    y = 30.4


# optional 
class Base(object):
    pass

class Something(Constants, Base):
    pass


s = Something()

print(s.x)
```

However, since it's just data I would probably just use some type of data structure, such as a dictionary, to hold them. I'm not sure why you would need to put them as class attributes, when any code could just reference them from the module just the same.

Comment: Creating a class you never intend to instantiate just to hold a bunch of attributes is a bit of an anti-pattern, IMHO. Modules themselves are first-class objects too; just pass around the module instead of creating a class and passing that around. I'll admit using it as a mixin could potentially be useful, but then you've got multiple inheritance going on (with seeing that it's just a simple class-var dump left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: @Ben That's what I said at the end. :)

Comment: Thanks. Actually you're right, a dictionary is probably a better way to hold them. I just like the idea of using 'instance.attribute' syntax

Answer (score 1):

There's always something like:

```
class something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        import constants
        for name in ['x', 'y', ...]:
            setattr(self, name, getattr(constants, name))
```

That has the advantage of avoiding repreating `self.X = constants.X` so very many times, and means you're only listing the names once in one place.

You *could* use this:

```
for name, value in constants.__dict__.iteritems():
    setattr(self, name, value)
```

To get all the names bound in `constants` without explicitly listing them, but I personally would not. It makes it much less clear what attributes `something` objects actually have, and it's *very* easy for Python modules to end up containing more names than you realise. For example, if you have to import another module (say, `math`) in `constants` in the process of defining all your constants, then you'll end up with an unexpected `math` attribute of all your `something` instances.

I think explicitly listing the names you mean to import is clearer. Plus, it means that you don't affect all your `something` instances if you discover you need to add more constants for some other part of your program to use (and if the constants can only ever have relevance to `something` then they really should be listed in `something`, not in an external module).

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it is much more clear to just explicitly list them.

Answer (score 0):

`from constants import x, y` just be sure you don't accidentally over ride your variables later (i.e. don't use generic names)