# What is a good way to maintain a set of constants in Python project?

Tags: python, dictionary, enums, standards

Have a .py file with below content ?

```
class Set1(Enum):
   A = 1
   B = 2

class Set2(Enum):
  hi=1
  hello=2
```

OR simply

```
Set1 = {"A":1,"B":2}
Set2 = {"C"="hi","D"="Hello"}
```

Please note that these constants will be used by different modules in the project.

Comment: One way would to create ``constants.py`` file with all the constants as shown here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343330/importing-a-long-list-of-constants-to-a-python-file

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you define constants in a file like this:

`some_file.py` :

```
FOO = 0
BAR = "baz"
```

And if you need to use it:

```
import some_file

print(some_file.FOO)
print(some_file.BAR)
```

Comment: So use of enum makes sense only when constants are related to one another in terms of order or sequence right ?

Comment: @ShubhamPandey enums make sense when you need *an enumerated type*.  So yes, they are some set of objects that are related, and they are all the same type.\

Answer (score 0):

If you have groups of related constants, such as the [`regex flags`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.A), then an `Enum` is the appropriate tool (e.g. your `hi` and `hello` in `Set2`).

For unrelated constants I would use the `Constant` class found in `aenum`<sup>1</sup>:

```
class MiscellaneousConstants(Constant):
    A = 1
    B = 2
```

`Constant`s are similar to `Enum`s in that you cannot rebind them, and they have nice reprs:

```
>>> MiscellaneousConstants.A
<MiscellaneousConstants.A: 1>

>>> MiscellaneousConstants.A = 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: cannot rebind constant <MiscellaneousConstants.A>
```

Typing the class name can be a bother, so to facilitate getting the `Constant` members into the global name space, `export` is provided:

```
from aenum import Constant, export

@export(globals())
class MiscellaneousConstants(Constant):
    A = 1
    B = 2
```

and in use:

```
>>> A
<MiscellaneousConstants.A: 1>
```

Note that, as is normal for Python, names at the global level can still be rebound:

```
>>> A = 9
>>> A
9
```

`Constant` class members, however, are still constant:

```
>>> MiscellaneousConstants.A
<MiscellaneousConstants.A: 1>

>>> MiscellaneousConstants.A = 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: cannot rebind constant <MiscellaneousConstants.A>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.