# What's the best way to initialise and use constants across Python classes?

Tags: python

Here's how I am declaring constants and using them across different Python classes:

```
# project/constants.py
GOOD = 1
BAD = 2
AWFUL = 3

# project/question.py
from constants import AWFUL, BAD, GOOD

class Question:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

Is the above a good way to store and use contant values?  I realise that after a while, the constants file can get pretty big and I could explicitly be importing 10+ of those constants in any given file.

Comment: Well first there is no constant variable in python , and second your global variable are they used in more than one module or just in one ?

Comment: They are used across different classes within that project.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

why not just use

```
import constants

def use_my_constants():
    print constants.GOOD, constants.BAD, constants.AWFUL
```

From the python zen:

> Namespaces are good. Lets do more of those!

**EDIT:** Except, when you do quote, you should include a reference and check it, because as others have pointed out, it should read:

> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

This time, I actually copied it from the source: [PEP 20 -- The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: ... Which is also an infinitely more approrpiate way to put it.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: Ouch. I stand corrected. I'll edit my post accordingly!

Comment: Another thing you can do to reduce typing is to use "import constants as CN" and "print(CN.GOOD)" etc.

Comment: For a moment I thought, constants is an actual python library, how nice it would have been, LoL. I didn't read the question. :-)

Comment: what is I have Constance with critical static critical data and I want to read it demo ini file and assign it to variable before using it, I tried writing methods but not able to call in in definition also tried with __init__ method but failed. I'm new to python anyway.

Answer (score 17):

You also have the option, if the constants are tied to a particular class and used privately within that class of making them specific to that class:

```
class Foo(object):
   GOOD = 0
   BAD = 1
   WTF = -1

   def __init__(self...
```

and away you go.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options:

1. Do it the way you're doing right now with a file of constants
2. Use a flat file and parse it once, pass a dictionary / class around
3. Query off to a database

From an overhead point of view, 1 and 2 are about the same. As for your question about importing specific constants, it's much easier to use one of the following conventions:

- `import constants; some_func(constants.AWFUL)`
- `from constants import *; some_func(AWFUL)`

Answer (score 3):

Try to look at the following links(one link contains a receipt from active state of how to implement a real constants):

[Importing a long list of constants to a Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343330/importing-a-long-list-of-constants-to-a-python-file)

[Create constants using a "settings" module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824455/python-constants)

[Can I prevent modifying an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711657/can-i-prevent-modifying-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I use a function as immutable constant, like this:

```
def test_immutable_constant():
    def GOOD():
        return 1

    good_value = GOOD()
    good_value = 2

    assert GOOD() == 1
    assert good_value == 2
```