# How can I tell Python to stop parsing in the middle of the source file?

Tags: python

In many situations I find myself wishing that I could tell Python to ignore a source file from a certain line onward, until the end of the file. Just one example of many is when translating code from another language to Python, function by function: After I translated one function, I want to test it, with the rest of the untranslated code still in the same file, and I hope not to parse it.

In other languages, doing this is easy. Shell has `exit 0` which basically causes everything after it to never be parsed. Perl has `__END__`. C or C++ do not have ignore-until-end-of-file specifically, but it's easy emulate it with a `#if 0` at some point and finally `#endif` at the end of the file.

My question is how can I do this in Python? I tried looking everywhere, and can't seem to find a solution!

To make the question more concrete, consider the following code:

```py
print(1)
exit(0)
@$@(% # this is not correct Python
```

This program fails. The `exit(0)` doesn't help because Python still parses everything after it. Not to mention that `exit(0)` is obviously not the right thing to do in an imported source file (my intention is to stop reading this source file - not to exit the whole program). My question is with what I can replace the "exit(0)" line that will make this program work (print "1" and that's it).

Comment: Yeah...you want triple quotes for sure.  I do this a lot.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't Python have multiline comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/397148/10077)

Comment: Related [Terminate importation of module non-fatally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217505/terminate-importation-of-module-non-fatally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose what you don't want parsed in triple quotes:

```
print(1)
"""
@$@(% # this is not correct Python
blah
dee
blah
blah
"""
```

Comment: Very good idea. It will indeed work for the use case where the code I want to ignore is in some other programming language, or pure junk. The only downside I see now is that It will not work for actual Python code which might itself use triple quotes somewhere. But as long as I know this is not the case, your solution indeed saves the day. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there are limitations for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can raise an exception, assuming you have some condition that is met or not

Inside the imported file

```
print("hi")
my_condition = True
if my_condition:
    raise Exception
print("nope")
```

and then wrap the import in a try block

```
try:
    import your_module
except Exception:
    print("source not fully read")
```

Comment: This solution doesn't solve my main concern: that the code after the "raise Exception" needs to be valid Python as well. If it has any syntax errors (or not even real Python), the import will fail.