# Use alias for a property in Python at module level

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following in Python 2.7:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
    @property
    def my_attr(self):
        ...

    @my_attr.setter
    def my_attr(self, value):
        ...
```

I use getter/setter so that I can do some logic in there.

Then I can call:

```
import myModule
test = myModule.MyClass()
test.my_attr = 9
```

I would like to use an alias at the module level so that I can do something like that:

```
import myModule
myModule.my_attr = 9
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What would that do, exactly?

Comment: I'm just trying to simplify the usage of my library. For example, instead of having myPackage.myModule.myClass.test = 9, I would like to do myPackage.myModule.test = 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely; the key is that modules are themselves objects.  First you need to make `MyClass` subclass the module type:

```
from types import ModuleType

class MyClass(ModuleType):
    ...
```

Then you *replace* the current module with an instance of MyClass:

```
import sys
sys.modules[__name__] = MyClass(__name__)
```

Note that this can be pretty confusing to static analysers and to people reading your code.

Comment: That seems to work. But what if I want to _append_ to the module instead of _replacing_?

Comment: @MasterMind something like `self.__dict__.update(real_module.__dict__)` should work.  Or you can replace `self.__dict__` with a `collections.ChainMap` (since 3.3).

Comment: Note that you have to be careful when doing this -- see accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365562/why-is-the-value-of-name-changing-after-assignment-to-sys-modules-name).

Answer (score 0):

To provide a special handling for some attributes of a module, you could define a proxy class that does the special handling and delegates the rest to the original module object:

```
"""
>>> import property_on_module
>>> property_on_module.attr = 1
set attr property
>>> property_on_module.attr
get attr property
1
"""
import sys

class Module(object):
    def __init__(self, module):
        self.__module = module

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.__module, name)

    @property
    def attr(self):
        print("get attr property")
        return self.__attr

    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        print("set attr property")
        self.__attr = value

if __name__ == "__main__": # test if run as a script
    import doctest
    sys.exit(doctest.testmod().failed)
else: # normal import, use `Module` class to provide `attr` property
    sys.modules[__name__] = Module(sys.modules[__name__])
```

`__getattr__` might not be enough; you could define `__getattribute__/__setattr__` in this case e.g., [`quickdraw.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/a011754fa77737e099b7#file-quickdraw-py) (based on [`sh.py`](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/8c1704914fda4f771fac5762f82e163c950fae84/sh.py#L1628)).