# properties on a module?

Tags: python, properties, module

This probably already looks like a duplicate; here's the scenario:

default_config.py:

```
unit_id = -1  # a serial number; int. -1 is a test unit, for example

def um():
    return unit_id % 60  # stagger uploads

upload_hour = 2  #am
upload_minute = property( um )  # <- something that works needed here...
```

config.py

```
from default_config import *
# Override defaults here, if necessary

unit_id = 12  # ACTUAL serial number...
```

some_file.py

```
import config as cfg

do_something(cfg.upload_hour, cfg.upload_minute)

print cfg.upload_minute * 5  # should be an int...?
```

So, the goals are:

- A specific config file can override the defaults, which works fine
- Some values which are calculated can be accessed - after the overrides are applied - but in a "transparent" way (ie. without the prop() brackets)

This seemed to be simple for python properties, but after various combinations, doesn't work. I guess its something to do with the function being defined on a module, not an object, and unbound first variables, etc...

Either I get a "property object" back, and can't then use operators on it, etc, or I can't get the value the property should calculate and return, or after many iterations I can't remember, some other error...

Comment: Suggest you [edit] your question and add something explicit that doesn't work.

Comment: The code as stated will import, etc - but doesn't work as per the stated API goal. I've added a print statement which I would like to work - the property should just be an int by this stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess its something to do with the function being defined on a
>   module, not an object...

Why not use an object then? :)

**default_config.py**

```
_DEFAULT_UNIT_ID = -1
_DEFAULT_UPLOAD_HOUR = 2
_MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60


class BaseConfig(object):
    def __init__(self, unit_id=_DEFAULT_UNIT_ID, upload_hour=_DEFAULT_UPLOAD_HOUR):
        self.unit_id = unit_id
        self.upload_hour = upload_hour

    @property
    def upload_minute(self):
        return self.unit_id % _MINUTES_PER_HOUR
```

**config.py**

```
from default_config import BaseConfig

# organized place to put non-default parameters
config_dict = {
    'unit_id': 12,
    'upload_hour': 3,
}

CONFIG = BaseConfig(**config_dict)
```

**some_file.py**

```
from config import CONFIG

print CONFIG.upload_hour, CONFIG.upload_minute  # "3 12"
```

I would also consider just combining default_config.py and config.py if there's no need to separate them, since it would be easier to see what keyword arguments the `BaseConfig` takes.

Comment: This is a good suggestion - thanks for looking at it from a different perspective. Things may go down this path, but I'm going to exhaust all possibilities the current way first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define special methods on modules, but entries in `sys.modules` don't have to be module objects, they can also be class instance objects. This means you can take advantage of their attribute-access special methods like this:

**default_config.py**

```
class DefaultConfig(object):
    unit_id = -1  # a serial number
    upload_hour = 2  # am

    @property
    def upload_minute(self):
        return self.unit_id % 60  # stagger uploads
```

**config.py**

```
import sys
from default_config import DefaultConfig

# override defaults
DefaultConfig.unit_id = 12

# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365562/why-is-the-value-of-name-changing-after-assignment-to-sys-modules-name
# as to why the _ref is necessary
_ref, sys.modules[__name__] = sys.modules[__name__], DefaultConfig()

# clean up this module's namespace
del sys, DefaultConfig
```

**some_file.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import config as cfg

def do_something(hour, minute):
    print('do_something({}, {}) called'.format(hour, minute))

do_something(cfg.upload_hour, cfg.upload_minute)
print(cfg.upload_minute * 5)
```

Output from running `some_file.py`:

```
do_something(2, 12) called
60
```