# Why can't a module be a context manager (to a 'with' statement)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, with-statement, contextmanager

Suppose we have the following `mod.py`:

```
def __enter__():
    print("__enter__<")

def __exit__(*exc):
    print("__exit__< {0}".format(exc))

class cls:
    def __enter__(self):
        print("cls.__enter__<")

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        print("cls.__exit__< {0}".format(exc))
```

and the following use of it:

```
import mod

with mod:
    pass
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 3, in <module>
    with mod:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

According to the documentation the documentation the `with` statement should execute as follows (I believe it fails at step 2 and therefore truncate the list):

> 1. The context expression (the expression given in the *with_item*) is evaluated to obtain a context manager.
> 2. The context manager’s `__exit__()` is loaded for later use.
> 3. The context manager’s `__enter__()` method is invoked.
> 4. etc...

As I've understood it there is no reason why `__exit__` could not be found. Is there something I've missed that makes a module not able to work as a context manager?

Comment: _Why_ exactly do you want / need this capability? What's a use-case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__exit__` is a *special method*, so Python looks it up on the *type*. The `module` type has no such method, which is why this fails.

See the [*Special method lookup* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) of the Python datamodel documentation:

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

Note that this applies to all special methods. For example, if you added a `__str__` or `__repr__` function to a module it'll not be called when printing the module, either.

Python does this to make sure type objects are hashable and representable too; if Python *didn't* do this then trying to put a class object into a dictionary would fail when a `__hash__` method was defined for that class (as that method would expect an instance to be passed in for `self`).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it easily for the reasons stated in @Martijn Pieters [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40606015/355230). However with a little extra work it *is* possible, because the values in `sys.modules` don't have to be instances of the built-in module class, they can be instances of your own custom class with the special methods a context manager requires.

Here's applying that to what you want to do. Given the following `mod.py`:

```
import sys

class MyModule(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print("__enter__<")

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        print("__exit__> {0}".format(exc))

# replace entry in sys.modules for this module with an instance of MyModule
_ref = sys.modules[__name__]
sys.modules[__name__] = MyModule()
```

And the following use of it:

```
import mod

with mod:
    print('running within context')
```

Will produces this output:

```
__enter__<
running within context
__exit__> (None, None, None)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365562/why-is-the-value-of-name-changing-after-assignment-to-sys-modules-name) question for information about why the `_ref` is needed.

Comment: at which point you have to ask yourself *why would you need to even do this*?

Comment: @Martijn: Replacing a module with an instance of a custom class is occasionally useful because it allows doing things that are impossible to do with a regular module object—like controlling attribute access—however I tend to agree that doing it so the module can be used as a context manager might be bit of a stretch.

Comment: Yes, I know there are use-cases, I'm just not sure that this is one of them.

Comment: @Martijn:  Just answering the OP's question—while simultaneously trying to avoid passing judgement without additional information regarding their motives.

Comment: I am nowhere near the quality of pythonista as Martijn - but this does just seem wrong to me as well. All is does is make the import line a bit shorter, but introduces 'magic' which can easily be lost.

Comment: @Tony: The only reason the it's done in two lines the code shown is because I didn't want to hardcode "modulename" into the code (because the file it is in is not named `modulename.py` on my system. In actual usage it can be imported just like any other: `import modulename`. Since that's distracting folks, I may take it out.

Comment: It isn't the soft import that I have issue with - I have plenty of my own code that does that to make the code flexible, data driven etc.  I have an issue with inserting a class into 'sys.modules'.  All it seems to do is save you the trouble of importing the class, and make any code wishing this a bit less readable

Comment: @Tony: I actually learned about this technique in one of Alex Martelli's _Python Cookbooks_. He said that being able to replace a module with a class instance was an intentional feature in Python's design (although not necessarily to allow using one as a context manager). As I said in an earlier, comment, I agree that using it to do this might be questionable, and mainly just wanted to show that, in fact, one can do it—but mostly just to make more folks aware of the capability.

Comment: What about changing the `__class__` attribute of the module for a class inheriting the Module type ?

Answer (score 1):

A softer version than the one proposed by Martineau, a little bit less polemic :

```
import sys

class CustomModule(sys.modules[__name__].__class__):
  """
  Custom module
  """
  def __enter__(self):
    print('enter')

  def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print('exit')


sys.modules[__name__].__class__ = CustomModule
```

Instead of replacing the module (wich may cause countless problems), just replace the class by one inheriting from the original class. This way, the original module object is kept, there is no need for another ref (preventing garbage collection), and it will work with any custom importer. Note the important fact that a module object is created and added to the sys.modules **BEFORE** the code of the module is executed.

Note that using this way, you can add any magic method

Comment: Clever — I like how it avoids the need for an additional reference that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40607430/355230) requires.