# Passing variable to file being imported?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, python-import

I have 3 python files: `login`, `teacher_ui`, and `student_ui`. All three of these use tkinter. The login file takes a name as an input and if the name is a valid table in a database, the login file imports the `student_ui` file to run it.

The problem I am having is that the student_ui file needs a variable called `name`, which is the input in `login`. I am struggling to import the variable into `student_ui`as it changes all the time.

My code in `login` to load the `student_ui` file is:

```
elif name_data in names_list:
    opening_window.destroy()
    import student_ui
```

This then runs `student_ui`, which provides a different interface. The code for `name_data` is: `name_data = name.get().lower()`

The line of code in `student_ui` that needs `name_data` is: `user_table_name = name_data`. This line is throwing a `NameError` because `name` is not defined.

Therefore, how would I make `student_ui` take the `name_data` from `login` when `login` loads `student_ui`?

Some of the code for the `student_ui` is:

```
number_words = {
                        "Forty Five" : 45,
                        ...
                        "Nine Thousand, Eight Hundred and Sixty Four" : 9864
}

user_table_name = name_data

query = 'SELECT _45 FROM {} ORDER BY runid DESC LIMIT 
3'.format(user_table_name)
c.execute(query)
status_1 = c.fetchall()
if ('true',) in status_1:
    status_1 = True
else:
    status_1 = False
```

There is also code for label, inputs, marking, and large amounts of database writing and reading.

Comment: How is your program structured, what runs the different files?

Comment: The `login` file runs the different files in the format:`if condition: import student_ui`  `elif other condition: import teacher_ui`.

Comment: And are the UI's built with classes etc or just code?

Comment: Just code, I didn't use classes as it seemed pointless.

Comment: You can't pass arguments directly to a module being imported, period. One workaround I have used is shown in [this ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/) which replaces the module with an instance of a class. Note there is one [minor caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365562/why-is-the-value-of-name-changing-after-assignment-to-sys-modules-name), but it's easily worked around. There are other techniques to pass data to the module indirectly (such through a file).

Comment: I would create a class and import that class from the module. In the constructor it would receive the name variable

Comment: Would that class be all the code in `student_ui` as there is lots of code not in functions.

Comment: Re: @IsaacDj suggestion: That would depend on what the code does. Some of it might have to be moved into methods of the class—like its `__init__()` method or new ones you'll need to create (and call somewhere).

Comment: @martineau yes indeed. it's basically a matter of comfort to the coder

Comment: 13smith_oliver: If you want more concrete and formal answers, you'll need to [edit] your question and include the code for the `student_ui` module. If it's too long or complex, you'll need to create an MCVE (see [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and put it in instead.

Answer (score 1):

Per [IsaacDj's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2307698/isaacdj): I would use classes.

First, I would encapsulate all of `student_ui.py`'s code into classes to prevent unexpected code execution:

```
# student_ui.py

class StudentUI:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_things(self):
        number_words = {
            "Forty Five" : 45,
            ...
            "Nine Thousand, Eight Hundred and Sixty Four" : 9864
        }

        query = 'SELECT _45 FROM {} ORDER BY runid DESC LIMIT 3'.format(self.name)

        c.execute(query)
        status_1 = c.fetchall()

        if ('true',) in status_1:
            status_1 = True
        else:
            status_1 = False
```

Then to make things easier, you could straight-up import `student-ui` - no having to conditionally import the module:

```
# login.py

from student_ui import StudentUI

def do_stuff(name_data):
    if name_data in names_list:
        opening_window.destroy()
        student_ui = StudentUI(name_data)
        student_ui.do_stuff()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_stuff()
```

You could also use [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to prevent `student_ui` from executing on import.