# How can I use super() in both elegant and safe (regarding Python module reloading) way?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I discovered an annoying behaviour of `reload()` (both Python 2 builtin and from `importlib`) that I am trying to walkarround.

I am analysing data in interactive Python interpreter. My code is organised in modules (both Python 2 and 3 compatible) which I often change.

Restarting the interpreter is not feasible due to long time of loading data, so I prefer to recursively reload modules instead.

The problem is that [`reload()` updates the code but preserves the module global scope](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) (it applies to [Python 3 `importlib.reload()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) as well). It seems to be harmful for methods using `super()` (it took me a while to realise what is going on).

The minimal failing example for a module bar.py:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
```

is:

```
>>> import bar
>>> class Foo(bar.Bar):
...     pass
... 
>>> reload(bar)
<module 'bar' from '[censored]/bar.py'>
>>> Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[censored]/bar.py", line 3, in __init__
    super(Bar, self).__init__()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I may:

1. [use `super()` without arguments in Python 3 manner](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super) (which is not
   compatible with Python 2),
2. abandon it and call `Bar.__init__(self)` instead ([which is harder to
   maintain](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super) and [discouraged](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)),
3. monkey-patch the class adding a class attribute containing a circular
   reference to the class itself.

None of the ideas I like. Is there any other way of dealing with the issue?

Comment: Your `bar.py` already fails because you put `super(Bar, self).__init__()` at class level instead of in an `__init__` method.

Comment: Your usage of `super` is invalid in fact. `super` is used within methods of a class not in the class body.

Comment: Also, reloading modules is just really hard to get right in general, and `reload` only handles the very simplest cases. Your best bet will always be to restart Python from scratch.

Comment: My bad, I missed a line when typing the example.

Comment: Don't retype it! Copy and paste from code you've actually run. Much safer.

Comment: @user2357112 agreed ;)

Comment: Typically I use `super(self.__class__, self).__init__()` on Python 2, I'm not sure if it works on Python 3

Comment: @bphi: **Never do that**, because it breaks as soon as you subclass that class and `self.__class__` is the subclass. If it was that simple, `super` never would have required the type argument in the first place.

Comment: @user2357112: updated

Comment: @bphi: user2357112 is right, I learned that the hard way. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because it's basically impossible to do anything elegantly and safely where module reloading is concerned. That kind of thing is super tricky to get right.

The specific way that problem is manifesting here is that `Foo`'s superclass is still the old `Bar`, but the old `Bar` refers to itself by name, and the `Bar` name now refers to the new `Bar` in the namespace where it's looking. The old `Bar` is trying to pass the new `Bar` to `super`.

---

I can give you some options. All of them are **inelegant** and **unsafe** and **probably going to give you weird surprises eventually**, but all that is also true about module reloading.

Probably the most easily-understood option is to rerun the `Foo` class definition to get a new `Foo` class descending from the new `Bar`:

```
reload(bar)
class Foo(bar.Bar):
    pass
```

New instances of `Foo` will then use the new `Bar`, and will not experience problems with `super`. Old instances will use the old `Foo` and the old `Bar`. They're not going to have problems with `__init__`, because that already ran, but they're likely to have other problems.

Another option you can take is to *update `Foo`'s superclass* so `Foo` now descends from the new `Bar`:

```
reload(bar)

Foo.__bases__ = (bar.Bar,)
```

New and old instances of `Foo` will then use the new `Bar`. Depending on what you changed in `Bar`, the new class may not be compatible with the old instances, especially if you changed what data `Bar` keeps on its instances or how `Bar.__init__` performs initialization.

Comment: In my real-life example modules reload their imports recursively, so I hope code differences would not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like what you really want it to do re-`import` the module. The following allow that (in both Python 2 and 3).

```
import bar
import sys

class Foo(bar.Bar):
    pass

# Manually reload module.
_saved_reference = sys.modules['bar']  # Needed for Python 2.
del sys.modules['bar']

import bar  # Re-import instead of reload().
Foo()  # No error.
```

Comment: What's `_saved_reference` for?

Comment: This solution has its own weird surprises, of course. Old references to `bar` and `Bar` will still refer to the old module and the old class, so `Foo` will still be using the old class, and any other modules that had imported `bar` will still have the old module. Reimporting packages this way is also likely to break access to submodules. Without restarting Python, any option is going to have weird surprises.

Comment: @user2357112: `_saved_reference` is needed because of something Python 2 does. See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365562/why-is-the-value-of-name-changing-after-assignment-to-sys-modules-name) of mine that discusses it.

Comment: Huh. I thought that was an effect of interpreter shutdown, not part of the module destructor.