# How do I use the sys.modules replacement trick in __init__.py on Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I attempted to use the `sys.modules` replacement trick described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668273/23845 but it does not work in the following case in Python 2:

```
# a/__init__.py
import sys

class AMod(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d

sys.modules[__name__] = AMod(sys.modules[__name__].__dict__)
```

And:

```
# a/sub.py
import a

z = True
```

Finally:

```
# b.py
import a.sub
```

This fails with:

```
pymodshenanigans ezyang$ python b.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a.sub
RuntimeError: sys.path must be a list of directory names
```

Is there a way to make this work? (It works on Python 3.)

Comment: Well, what is `sys.path` at this point?

Comment: It works for me

Comment: You likely need to keep a reference to the module before replacing it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365562/why-is-the-value-of-name-changing-after-assignment-to-sys-modules-name

Comment: martineau got it right. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

@martineau is right: you have to retain a reference to the old module. This version works:

```
# a/__init__.py
import sys

class AMod(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.__dict__ = m.__dict__
        self.old_mod = m

sys.modules[__name__] = AMod(sys.modules[__name__])
```