# How to assign a __call__ method to a module/package?

Tags: python, methods, module

This might be a dumb question, but I did some googling and digging on SO and came up short of a proper answer. So I'll just ask:

Is it possible to assign a `__call__` method to a Python module or package?

What I mean is, instead of calling a method from the module/package's namespace, could I call an assigned method directly?

How it is now:

```py
import foo

foo.bar(123)
```

What I want to do:

```py
import foo

foo(123)
```

If this isn't possible, what would it take to monkeypatch in a feature like this? (That might be asking a lot)

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't **need** the module itself to be called, I was just wondering since it seemed more semantically appealing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like that.

#### `foo_module.py`

```
class Foo:
    def __call__(self, arg):
        print(f'Foo({arg!r}) called')

_ref, sys.modules[__name__] = sys.modules[__name__], Foo()
```

---

#### `main.py`

```
import foo_module

foo_module(123)  # -> Foo(123) called
```

Comment: ooo, that's a pretty hacky way of doing it, but it works, so no complaints from me! thanks!

Comment: It may be hacky, but I learned about it a book by the venerable @[Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli), one of the true masters of the language. See his answer to [Can modules have properties the same way that objects can?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880530/can-modules-have-properties-the-same-way-that-objects-can) for another example.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll take a look

Comment: Note: I just changed `foo_module` a little to prevent a problem I ran into once—see [Why is the value of __name__ changing after assignment to sys.modules\[\_\_name\_\_\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365562/why-is-the-value-of-name-changing-after-assignment-to-sys-modules-name)

Answer (score 0):

I thought that you could name the file hello.py then do:

```
class hello:
   def hi():
     return "hello"
```

then in the main file do:

```
from hello import hello
hello.hi()
```

Comment: While I agree that this is a more sensical setup, this isn't what they're after.