# Making a variable immutable in Python

Tags: python, class, immutability

```
class Foo(float):
   ...

C = Foo(1.23)
```

given a class/obj definition like this, is there any way for me to make C read-only?  I want it to raise an error if `C = ...` is ever called after the object C is initialized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a constant in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/how-do-i-create-a-constant-in-python)

Comment: What do you mean by "immutable"? Do you mean changing the state of the object referred to by the name `C`? Or do you mean reassigning the name `C` to refer to a different value?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice reassigning the name C

Comment: No, there is no way to prevent reassigning a name in Python.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner not quite, that is talking about changing the attributes in the object at C, I want it so that the name C cannot be reassigned

Comment: "Immutable" is the wrong word for that. I think the right one is "read-only".

Comment: @wjandrea yes, will update question to match.

Comment: Python does not have immutable variables.

Comment: What you are asking for is akin to Java's `final` qualifier. This is different than "immutable".

Comment: Quick note, `C` is a name, not an object. This is an instance of `Foo`, not `C`. This may seem like splitting hairs, but it's an important distinction in python. The *value* `Foo(1.28)` is referred to by name `C`, and can be referred to by many other names. `a = b = c = Foo(1.28)` still produces only one instance of `Foo` here

Comment: @C.Nivs so then is there any way for python to recognize that the name ```C``` has changed what it is pointing at?

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones python doesn't provide any way for you to accomplish what you desire here.

Comment: It's impossible, but you might find my answer to [Can I prevent modifying an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711657/can-i-prevent-modifying-an-object-in-python) useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. You can make the `Foo` object immutable but you can't make variables with references to it immutable. The object doesn't own the variable or have any control over it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

No matter what you assign to `C`, `C` itself is not an instance of whatever class you create. `C` is a variable. Operations that operate on the variable, like `C = something_new`, don't even look at your object except to decrement the refcount. You can define how operations on your object behave, but you can't redefine the semantics of the variable itself.

Comment: So could I make it so that when the refcount is decremented, it produces an error?

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones you cannot without hacking the interpreter itself.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is a big F but imma try anyways.

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones: Refcounts go up and down all the time. Even if you could raise an error when your object's refcount goes down, doing so would render your objects completely unusable. It'd be like a doomsday device that goes off whenever someone stops looking at it (or blinks while looking at it).

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite what you want to accomplish but I think the following solution is close to your goal. You could consider implementing a singleton. (taken from [www.python.org](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__.))

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        it = cls.__dict__.get("__it__")
        if it is not None:
            return it
        cls.__it__ = it = object.__new__(cls)
        it.init(*args, **kwds)
        return it
    def init(self, *args, **kwds):
        pass
```

Now you can test with:

```
>>> class MySingleton(Singleton):
...     def init(self):
...         print "calling init"
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "calling __init__"
... 
>>> x = MySingleton()
calling init
calling __init__
>>> assert x.__class__ is MySingleton
>>> y = MySingleton()
calling __init__
>>> assert x is y
>>>
```

You could modify this example to raise an ex or a warning if somebody tries to reassign it. Also if you want your singleton attributes to be immutable you could consider using tuples or namedtuples to accomplish this.