# Delete a key and value from an OrderedDict

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am trying to remove a key and value from an `OrderedDict` but when I use:

```
dictionary.popitem(key)
```

it removes the last key and value even when a different key is supplied. Is it possible to remove a key in the middle if the dictionary?

Comment: Read [the docs for `OrderedDict.popitem`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem): *"The pairs are returned in LIFO order if `last` is true or FIFO order if false."*

Comment: `dictioary.popitem()` doesn't take an argument, use `dictionary.pop(key)`.

Comment: @martineau you should also follow that link - `.popitem` *does* take an argument, `last`, otherwise the OP would get a `TypeError` rather than unexpected behaviour

Comment: @jonrsharpe: True, `OrderedDict.popitem()` _does_ take an optional argument, but it's not a key in the dictionary -- therefore the OP should use the inherited [`dict.pop(key)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=pop#dict.pop) method, especially if they want the associated value of the key being removed returned as a result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete an item from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-item-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-del_stmt):

```
del dct[key]
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dct = OrderedDict()
>>> dct['a'] = 1
>>> dct['b'] = 2
>>> dct['c'] = 3
>>> dct
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
>>> del dct['b']
>>> dct
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('c', 3)])
>>>
```

In fact, you should always use `del` to remove an item from a dictionary.  `dict.pop` and `dict.popitem` are used to remove an item **and return the removed item** so that it can be saved for later.  If you do not need to save it however, then using these methods is less efficient.

Answer (score 14):

You can use pop, popitem removes the last by default:

```
d = OrderedDict([(1,2),(3,4)])
d.pop(your_key)
```