# How to remove many elements in a very big dict?

Tags: python

I have a very large `dict`, and I want to `del` many elements from it. Perhaps I should do this:

```
new_dict = { key:big_dict[key] for key in big_dict if check(big_dict[key] }
```

However, I don't have enough memory to keep both `old_dict` and `new_dict` in RAM. Is there any way to deal?

---

Add:

I can't del elements one by one. I need to do a test for the values to find which elements I want to del.

I also can't del elements in a for loop like:

```
for key in dic: 
    if test(dic(key)): 
        del dic[key]
```

It case a error... Can't change len(dic) in the loop...

My God... I even can't make a set to remember keys to del, there are too much keys...

I see, if dict class don't have a function to do this, perhaps the only way to do this is to bug a new computer...

Comment: You could use a database.

Comment: What's wrong with using a simple `for` loop and `del`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete an element from a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options:

- Make a new 'dict' on disk, for which `pickle` and `shelve` may be helpful.
- Iterate through and build up a list of keys until it reaches a certain size, delete those, and then repeat the iteration again, allowing you to make a bigger list each time.
- Store the keys to delete in terms of their index in `.keys()`, which can be more memory efficient. This is OK as long as the dictionary is not modified between calls to `.keys()`. If about half of the elements are to be deleted, do this with a binary sequeunce (1 = delete, 0 = keep). If a vast majority of elements are to be deleted (or not deleted) store the appropriate keys as integers in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could try iterating through the dictionary and deleting the element that you do not require by

```
del big_dict[key]
```

This way you wouldn't be making copies of the dictionary.

Comment: I can't del elements one by one. And I also can't del elements in a for loop just like: for key in dic: if test(dic(key)): del key, it case a error... I even can't make a set to remember what to del, there are too mush keys and I have little memory... Perhaps I should get a stronger computer.

Comment: What are the specifications of the computer that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
big_dict.pop("key", None)
```

refer here 
[How to remove a key from a python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-to-remove-a-key-from-a-dictionary)