# Python: how to remove a value from a dict if it exactly matches the key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, frame

Being that the key has multiple values and I want to remove the one that is the same as the key itself? That is, I have a dictionary `jumps`:

```
jumps = {'I6': ['H6', 'I6', 'I5'], 'T8' : ['T6', 'S6', 'T8']}
```

And I want to delete the value `'I6'` from the `'I6'` key and also `'T8'` from the `'T8'` key. How could I do this? I'm getting mixed up in parsing the strings versus the values.

Comment: The answer can be found from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-item-from-a-dictionary). This is duplicate question.

Comment: @bismute: in that answer an **entire** key and its corresponding value is deleted, here the values are "manipulated".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a *one-liner* with both *dictionary comprehension* and *list comprehension*:

```
result = {k:[vi for vi in v if k != vi] for k,v in jumps.items()}
```

This results in:

```
>>> {k:[vi for vi in v if k != vi] for k,v in jumps.items()}
{'T8': ['T6', 'S6'], 'I6': ['H6', 'I5']}
```

Note that you will remove **all** elements from the lists that are equal to the key. Furthermore the remove process is done for **all** keys.

The code works as follows: we iterate over every *key-value* pair `k,v` in the `jumps` dictionary. Then for *every* such pair, we construct a key in the resulting dictionary, and associate `[vi for vi in v if k != vi]` with it. That is a list comprehension where we filter out all values of `v` that are equal to `k`. So only the `vi`s remain (in that order) that are `k != vi`.

Comment: This makes so much sense and works perfectly, and moreover, thank you for your helpful explanation! I will mark this as the answer when I am allowed to!

Answer (score 6):

There is a built in command, called `remove` that will remove an item from a list.   We can start by accessing the element from our `dictionary` by using a string key.  That value, happens to be a list, that we can then use the `remove` command on.

Here's your list to demonstrate:

```
jumps = {
    'I6': [ # we are accessing this value that happens to be a list
        'H6',
        'I6', #then Python will sort for and remove this value
        'I5'
    ],
    'T8' : [
        'T6',
        'S6',
        'T8'
    ]
}



jumps = {'I6': ['H6', 'I6', 'I5'], 'T8' : ['T6', 'S6', 'T8']}

jumps['I6'].remove('I6')
jumps['T8'].remove('T8')
print(jumps)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for key in jumps:
    jumps[key].remove(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
jumps = {'I6': ['H6', 'I6', 'I5'], 'T8' : ['T6', 'S6', 'T8']}

key = 'I6'

if key in jumps[key]:
    jumps[key].remove(key)

print(jumps)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other possible way might be:

```
{vals.remove(val) for key,vals in jumps.items() for val in vals if val == key}
```

Since, it is referencing to the values list or array, the removal from list will affect in values of `jumps`.

Comment: After the call, it would change the `jumps` though. For the time complexity it may not be efficient though, however wouldn't it be space efficient since we are not using anything except `jumps`  ( `{None}` would be extra space)?