# Can we delete or remove a value of any key in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose a dictionary is:

```
sd = {'q':1,'w':2,'e':4}
```

i know we can delete a pair though deleting respective key? but can we just delete a value? i got this question in a interview thats why i asked here.

Comment: You can delete by `del sd['q']` so that `q` and its respective value gets deleted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete an element from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary)

Comment: @kvmahesh well i know we can delete a pair though deleting respective key? but can we just delete a value? i got this question in a  interview thats why i asked here.

Comment: Answer would be 'No, you can not delete a value from a dictionary'

Comment: No, the best you can do is to replace the value, eg with `None`, or some default value. Eg, `default = object(); sd['q'] = default`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, No. You can't delete a value in a key-value pair but you can set the value to be None.