# How to make a list of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make variables like this:

```
Var1 = 0
Var2 = 0
Var3 = 0
Var4 = 0
```

into something like this:

```
allvar = (Var1 = 0, Var2 = 0, Var3 = 0, Var4 = 0)
```

I want a list like this because I want to use the `remove()` function to remove variables as the user inputs a specific thing.

Comment: Why a list? Why not a dict?

Comment: In a dictionary you can delete an item keyed by one of your vars with either "del" or "pop". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a dictionary for that?

This way you could add and remove values in/from your dictionary just as you wanted.

```
my_dict = {
   'var1': 0,
   'var2': 0,
    ...
}
```

You can delete by doing `my_dict.pop('var1')` if you need the value back or `del my_dict['var1']` otherwise and add items with `my_dict['var3'] = 0`.

Comment: Your code for the deletion of an element is too complicated. `del my_dict['var1']` is a lot clearer and with less overhead.

Comment: pop is useful if you need the value back, but I added the `del` way too for the other use cases, thank you!