# How to delete a value from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, del

How can I delete a value, for example John, out of the dictionary?

```
data = {'Player': ['John','Steffen'], age: [25,26]} 
data.pop("Player","John")
```

I just can’t find how I can delete a key like Player.

Comment: The answer is right there in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to remove "John" from the **list** stored in the dictionary. You first have to get a reference to that list, this can be done with the "Player" key. Then you can use the `remove` method of the list class to remove an item from it.

An example I think solves your problem is

```py
data = {'Player': ['John','Steffen'], age: [25,26]} 
data['Player'].remove('John') # First reference the list, then remove an item from it
```

I'd take a guess and say the list of ages corresponds to the list of players, so you'd have to also remove John's age from there.

Comment: Thank you really much. You could solve my Problem :D

Comment: Then please mark it as the answer so others can find it too :) @SaschaSteger

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a key and its values from dictionaries like this: `del data['Player']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary