# Deleting a key from dictionary keys view

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This probably a very basic question but having difficulty search for the correct answer. I have a Python dictionary named raw_data and am extracting the keys separately as follows:

```
features = raw_data.keys()
```

A few specific elements of the keys need to be deleted.

```
del features[137]
del features[160]
del features[181]
```

The above code however throws an error:

```
'dict_keys' object doesn't support item deletion
```

What is the correct way to delete a key form dictionary keys object?

Comment: `features = list(raw_data.keys()); del ...`. If you want to delete keys from dict itself `del raw_data[key]`

Comment: Is there any issue with converting to a `list` and then deleting?

Comment: This is part of a bigger code that I can't change too much

Comment: I had it as key object...changed it to key view

Comment: @Ravi: If this is code that was written for Python 2 (where `.keys()` returned a `list`), just wrap the original use of `.keys()` in the `list` constructor.

Comment: Also: [Delete an element from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5844672/7851470)

Comment: Do you really want to delete from the dict_view objects and not from the dictionary itself? If yes, what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Delete it from the dict instead.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You were right. This was an issue with the code being in Python 2. Runs perfectly fine in Python 2 environment.

Answer (score 2):

'dict_keys' is a *view*-object.

> It provides dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes.
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Hence it does not make sense to delete keys in the *view* without changing the dictionary itself. To delete the keys in the dictionary itself, see @ailin's answer. Following the deletion of keys in the dictionary, the keys will also be deleted in your dict_keys-view object.

If, however, you simply want a list with relevant keys, you can either convert the dict_keys object to a list and filter, or iterate over your dict_keys-object directly and filter the ones you do not need.

```
relevant_keys = [x for x in features if x not in [137, 160, 181]]
```