# How to remove specific element from the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

How to remove a specific element or data from the dictionary? Suppose I have this dictionary

```
data = {
    'name': 'Instagram',
    'follower_count': 346,
    'description': 'Social media platform',
    'country': 'United States'
}
```

and I don't want the element `'follower_count': 346` to be printed. What should be the operation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete an element from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use dictionary built in **pop()** method
which accept the key name as a parameter and which will remove the specified key value pair off the dictionary.

in your case it will be

```
data = { 'name': 'Instagram', 'follower_count': 346, 'description': 'Social media platform', 'country': 'United States' }

print(data.pop('follower_count'))
```

Comment: You're welcome, I wish you a very fun journey in Learning more about programming. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use ***pop***

```
data = { 'name': 'Instagram', 'follower_count': 346, 'description':'Social media platform', 'country': 'United States' }
data.pop("follower_count")
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'country': 'United States', 'description': 'Social media platform', 'name': 'Instagram'}
```