# I am trying to filter out non English words out of the dictionary and add only English words back with python but I have no idea how to do so

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import enchant

df1 = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\teeny\OneDrive - Singapore Institute Of Technology\SIT\1002 programming fundamentals\Data Cleaner project\Data Cleaner project\Cleaned Data.xlsx')

dict ={}
dict = df1

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
for words in dict:
    d.check(words)
```

Comment: 1. Don't name your variables `dict`, `list`, or other builtin types. Doing so shadows the type and can lead to bugs that are hard to diagnose. 2. You want to _remove_ an item from your (badly-named) `dict` dictionary. Did you do a [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+remove+item+from+dict) for that? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), [How much research?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)
and how to provide a [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete an element from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know what your Excel file looks like.
For now, I assumed that you have a list of words, in my code `word_list`. **This list contains all words**.
Then use an **empty list** to add all English words. In a `loop`, you go through your list word for word and check if it is English. You get back a [Boolean](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_booleans.asp). If this **boolean is True, add the current word to the list**. You could also write:

```
if d.check(word) == True:
```

But the code at the bottom is shorter.

```
import enchant

word_list = ['Hello', 'way', 'Backfisch']
english_word_list = []

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")

for word in word_list:
    if d.check(word):
        english_word_list.append(word)

print(english_word_list)
```

Judging by your question I would recommend going through this tutorial again to understand what you are doing: [Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_intro.asp)

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd suggest explaining what you're using enchant for.