# python how to update dictionary object with selected Tags only

Tags: python

How can I update the dictionary object to get selected Tags only. For example in below I only want to get Id, and Locations

```
InputString: 
{
1235 : {'Id':1, 'Product' : 'Prod1, 'Location' : 'NY'},
1236 : {'Id':2, 'Product' : 'Prod2, 'Location' : 'NJ'}
1237 : {'Id':3, 'Product' : 'Prod3, 'Location' : 'CT'}
}
```

Result

```
OutputString: 
{
1235 : {'Id':1, 'Location' : 'NY'},
1236 : {'Id':2, 'Location' : 'NJ'}
1237 : {'Id':3, 'Location' : 'CT'}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete an element from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dict comprehensions like so:

```
InputString= {1235 : {'Id':1, 'Product' : 'Prod1', 'Location' : 'NY'}, 1236 : {'Id':2, 'Product' : 'Prod2', 'Location' : 'NJ'}, 1237 : {'Id':3, 'Product' : 'Prod3', 'Location' : 'CT'}}
OutputString = {d: {k: v for k,v in InputString[d].items() if k in ['Id', 'Location']} for d in InputString}
print(OutputString)
```

Output:

```
{1235: {'Id': 1, 'Location': 'NY'}, 
1236: {'Id': 2, 'Location': 'NJ'}, 
1237: {'Id': 3, 'Location': 'CT'}}
```

You can also make a list of the keys you would like to keep and easily update it to get various combinations:

```
wanted = ['Id', 'Location']
InputString= {1235 : {'Id':1, 'Product' : 'Prod1', 'Location' : 'NY'}, 1236 : {'Id':2, 'Product' : 'Prod2', 'Location' : 'NJ'}, 1237 : {'Id':3, 'Product' : 'Prod3', 'Location' : 'CT'}}
OutputString = {d: {k: v for k,v in InputString[d].items() if k in wanted} for d in InputString}
print(OutputString)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do operations like this is to use a `pandas.DataFrame` object from the Python `pandas` module - see https://pandas.pydata.org/

In this case it's not necessary but it's generally a good module to use for data processing like this. Note that it must be installed.

Here is how you would use it:

```py
import pandas as pd

inp = pd.DataFrame({
 1235: {"Id": 1, "Product": "Prod1", "Location": "NY"},
 1236: {"Id": 2, "Product": "Prod2", "Location": "NJ"},
 1237: {"Id": 3, "Product": "Prod3", "Location": "CT"}
}).T

out = inp[["Id", "Location"]]
print(out)
```

If you want to turn `out` back to a dictionary you can replace the last line with this:

```py
print(out.to_dict("index"))
```