# Copy a dictionary into a new variable without maintaining the link with previous one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to copy a dictionary into a new variable without maintaining the link with previous variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to copy a dictionary in python 3.1 and edit ONLY the copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-in-python-3-1-and-edit-only-the-copy)

Answer (score 20):

```
from copy import deepcopy

new_dict = deepcopy(orig_dict)
```

dict.copy() creates shallow copies, which means, if your dictionary contains other container-objects like list, tuples, etc. they will be referenced again and not duplicated!

You can try for yourself with:

```
a = {1:{1:2}}
print id(a[1])
>>> 159584844

b = a.copy()
print id(b[1])
>>> 159584844

c = deepcopy(a)
print id(c[1])
>>> 159575276
```

Comment: Depending on the OP's requirements, this is not always a problem.  He was rather sparse on the details though.  If `.copy` was not ever a good tool, why does it exist?

Comment: .copy is an excellent tool, but as you mentioned the OP was very vague and so i interpreted his question slightly different from you. I can't even remember if i ever used deepcopy in an non-experimental code.

Comment: Point taken... I guess answering these questions can be a bit of a mind-reading game, huh?

Answer (score 7):

The `.copy` method on the dictionary should suffice.

```
dict1 = {'foo': 'bar'}
dict2 = dict1.copy()

dict1['bar'] = 'baz'
dict2['bar'] = 'bif'

print(dict1, dict2)
```

Ths outputs:

```
{'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 'baz'} {'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 'bif'}
```

If you want to remove reference to `dict1` completely, you can just `del dict1`.

If you're concerned about references to vars *inside* the dictionary, you can use `deepcopy` from the `copy` module.

Answer (score 6):

See the [dict.copy method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy)

There is no such thing as "copy an object **into** a new variable". You can copy an object; this creates a new object. An object may have 0, 1, or many names (what you are calling a "variable"). It is up to you whether you give the new object a name -- e.g. `foo = d.copy()` -- or leave it nameless -- e.g. `some_function(d.copy())`.

An object can be copied with a shallow copy or a deep copy. See the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html). Does a deep copy achieve what you meant by "without maintaining the link with previous variable"? If not, please clarify.

Comment: +1 for the comment on this horrid expression in Python : "copy ... INTO a new variable"

Comment: Nice!
I was very confused about a dictionary getting altered when all I wanted to do was alter a single item... I kind of just resigned that it happened for a few weeks till I found this :)

Answer (score 3):

You can access a dict's entry and remove it in one step using dict.pop().  Here is a creation of a dict dd, and then the entry by entry extraction from dd and construction of zz:

```
>>> dd = dict(zip("ABC","123"))
>>> print dd
{'A': '1', 'C': '3', 'B': '2'}
>>> zz = dict((k,dd.pop(k)) for k in dd.keys())
>>> print zz
{'A': '1', 'C': '3', 'B': '2'}
>>> print dd
{}
```

So after creating zz, all of the values have been removed from dd.  If you wanted to do something selective, add an `if condition` to the dict:

```
>>> dd = dict(zip("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", range(1,27)))
>>> vowels = "AEIOU"
>>> zz = dict((k,dd.pop(k)) for k in dd.keys() if k not in vowels)
>>> dd
{'A': 1, 'E': 5, 'I': 9, 'O': 15, 'U': 21}
>>> zz
{'C': 3, 'B': 2, 'D': 4, 'G': 7, 'F': 6, 'H': 8, 'K': 11, 'J': 10, 'M': 13, 'L': 12, 'N': 14, 'Q': 17, 'P': 16
, 'S': 19, 'R': 18, 'T': 20, 'W': 23, 'V': 22, 'Y': 25, 'X': 24, 'Z': 26}
```