# Why don't Python dictionaries treat keys independently in this script?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value, python-2.6

I'm expecting my frustration to be overridden with some enlightenment - here's a minimal version of the script to demonstrate the problem:

First I create a dictionary:

```
dic  = {
    'foo':{}, 
    'bar':{}
    }
```

Then we instantiate a template dictionary that can be iteratively appended 
to keys of `dic`:

```
appendic= {  
    'is':'',       #  '' is a terminal value to be replaced later
}
```

So here we append `appendic` to each of the keys in `dic`:

```
dic['foo'] = appendic
dic['bar'] = appendic
```

Now we replace the terminal values, '', with something meaningful:

```
dic['foo']['is'] = 'foo'
dic['bar']['is'] = 'bar'
```

At this point, my intuition tells me that if we call:

`print(dic['foo']['is'])` we get `'foo'`

But instead Python returns `'bar'` ... to my un-trained mind that is counter-intuitive.

**Questions:**

- How can I tell Python to keep the keys of dic independent?
- Why is this the default behaviour? What use cases does this have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you assign a `appendic` to two different keys, Python doesn't make a copy. It assigns a reference instead.

As a result, both `dic['please_make_me_Foo']` and `dic['dont_make_him_Bar']` refer to the *same object*. These are not separate dictionaries, they are both the same object, the one `appendic` *also* references to.

If you expected these to be separate dictionaries, create a copy of `appendic` instead. The `dict.copy()` method creates a shallow copy of a dictionary:

```
dic['please_make_me_Foo']= appendic.copy()
dic['dont_make_him_Bar'] = appendic.copy()
```

Shallow means that a new dictionary is created and all references to keys and values contained are copied over.

If `appendic` itself contains values that are also dictionaries, these would not be copied. The new copy and `appendic` would both refer to the same values. In most cases, that's not a problem because most primitive values (strings, integers, etc.) are immutable, and you never notice references are shared as you replace such values with new ones.

Comment: Cheers again @Martijn Pieters, would you happen to know cases where this can be useful? (I actually wanted to know a little of why the default behaviour acts the way it does)

Comment: @hello_there_andy: Loads of places where this is useful; the whole of Python is built on top of objects being referenceable from multiple locations.

Comment: @hello_there_andy: If Python made a copy of the object each time you stored a reference to it, you'd need a lot more memory to run your code, for starters.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate of at least a hundred questions, which you should know because you probably answered half of them. Why not close this or at least the next one as a duplicate instead? I'll even help you search for a suitable one once I'm back at a pc and not on mobile...

Comment: @hello_there_andy:  This is just how assignment in Python works.  Since you were suprised, I suggest reading [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @l4mpi: I'd love to find a suitable one. We really need a more generic 'halp my dictionary / list / set / custom class is being shared' post somewhere as a dupe target.

Comment: I did do some searching for dupes, but there's many unhelpful titles, I originally typed "why does the python dict behave like this" and seeing so many of those made me try a little harder on the title

Comment: @hello_there_andy: we didn't expect you to find the dupe; when you don't understand yet that Python stores references to objects the behaviour can be hard to search for, sure. What l4mpi is referring to is that he feels I should know better and have found you a dupe. :-)

Comment: @hello_there_andy: if a suitable dupe is found, don't worry. Your question will then serve as a signpost to the other question, for future searchers to find.

Comment: I did some searching, sadly I couldn't find a good generic question. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2465921) would fit here (among a few others), but for the general case a question/answer should at least explain immutability and give a short overview of references (and how it doesn't matter if you assign it to a variable/function argument/dict entry/etc). Creating a canonical question covering the most common cases would probably be a good idea. There's also the reverse where people ask why immutable objects don't behave this way but that's probably too broad to cover as well...

Answer (score 4):

You make a dict:

```
appendic= {  
    'Python_made_me':''
}
```

Add it to your other dict *twice*

```
dic['please_make_me_Foo']= appendic
dic['dont_make_him_Bar'] = appendic
```

And set the single dict's `Python_made_me` value *twice*

```
dic['please_make_me_Foo']['Python_made_me'] = 'Foo'
dic['dont_make_him_Bar']['Python_made_me']  = 'Bar'
```

But because they're *the same dict*, **the second line overwrites the first**

If you need to copy it, you need to use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) method:

```
dic['please_make_me_Foo']= appendic.copy()
dic['dont_make_him_Bar'] = appendic.copy()
```

Answer (score 3):

ok, I'm just going to write this as a complement to the other answers. When you manipulate a dictionary, you manipulate the *reference* to an instance, which is the root cause of your mistake. Using `hex(id(foo))` you get the memory address of `foo`, so let's show the address of `d` instance in the following example to make that *tangible*:

```
>>> hex(id(d))
'0x10bd95e60'
>>> hex(id(e[1]))
'0x10bd95e60'
>>> hex(id(f[1]))
'0x10bd95e60'
```

so if you add or remove values from `e[1]`, you're actually changing the same *instance* as the one pointed by `d`, and as a dictionary is mutable, i.e. you can change values within.

Now you're wondering why that does not happen when you're handling integers? Because, in fact it does, it's just that integers are not mutable:

```
>>> i = 1
>>> hex(id(i))
'0x10ba51e90'
>>> j = i
>>> hex(id(j))
'0x10ba51e90'
>>> i = 2
>>> hex(id(i))
'0x10ba51eb0'
```

i.e. i is pointing to another place in the memory.

It's possible to create a *mutable* integer though, by using a class:

```
>>> class Integer:
...   def __init__(self, i):
...     self.i = i
... 
>>> i = Integer(2)
>>> hex(id(i))
'0x10bd9b410'
>>> j = i
>>> hex(id(j))
'0x10bd9b410'
>>> j.i = 2
>>> i.i
2
>>> hex(id(i))
'0x10bd9b410'
```

In order to create a new instance of the same dictionary, you need to use the `copy()` member of a dict:

```
>>> hex(id(d))
'0x10bd95e60'
>>> w = d.copy()
>>> x = d.copy()
>>> y = d.copy()
>>> hex(id(w))
'0x10bd96128'
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x10bd95f80'
>>> hex(id(y))
'0x10bd96098'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dic['please_make_me_Foo']= appendic
dic['dont_make_him_Bar'] = appendic
```

`appendic` is an object - you are assigning a reference to the same object to both keys in `dic`. So when you change one, you change both.

Try this instead:

```
dic['please_make_me_Foo']= appendic.copy()
dic['dont_make_him_Bar'] = appendic.copy()
```