# How to remove set element in copied object

Tags: python, copy, set

The following code removes a set element from a copied dictionary, yet both dictionaries are changed.  How can have dic1 remain unchanged?

```
dic1 = {'a': set([1,2])}
dic2 = dic1.copy()
dic2['a'].discard(1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import copy

dic1 = {'a': set([1,2])}
dic2 = copy.deepcopy(dic1)
dic2['a'].discard(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

learn about [copy — Shallow and deep copy operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to understand why `copy` doesn't work, but `deepcopy` works