# How to ensure keys (or values) are of a specified data type in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, types

My python program uses dicts and there are a massive amount of "if" statements just for checking the type of the retrieved value.

I want to avoid this but instead do it a more programatically correct way.

Here is an example:

```
# golddb should only contain str keys and int values
golddb = dict()

def gainGold(playername):
  global golddb
  golddb[playername] += 1  # error may happen if I try to += a non-int type
  golddb[playername] = "hello"  # I want python to give an error when I try to assign a str to be a value in the dict
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code and input data examples? The question is incomplete.

Comment: are you aware of `type()` and yes your question is very vague, try to provide some code

Comment: check this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: @Ni https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference Check this. Can numpy be a JsonProperty? If it can't, it won't be of help to me.

Comment: I'm suggesting to use numpy structures instead of python dict to ensure data types

Answer (score 5):

To verify that all keys/values of a `dict` are of a particular type you could use the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function:

```
if all(isinstance(k, str) for k in playerdb):
    print("all keys are strs")
```

To enforce the types when *storing* values you could use a custom function to mediate access to the dictionary or, better yet,  subclass `dict` and override the `__setitem__` method, e.g.:

```
>>> class mydict(dict):
...     def __setitem__(self, key, val):
...         if not isinstance(key, str):
...             raise ValueError("key must be a str")
...         if not isinstance(val, int):
...             raise ValueError("value must be an int")
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)
...
>>> d = mydict()
>>> d["key"] = 1
>>> d["key"] = "value"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __setitem__
ValueError: value must be an int
```

Comment: Very helpful and thanks! But how do I parase mydict as a dict into a JsonProperty? Will casting it work? "d as dict" https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference

Comment: @Ryan: you can use `dict(d)` to get a `dict` instance, but since `mydict` **is-a** `dict`, you shouldn't be needing this

Comment: @eugeney Since mydict may define new members not present in dict, wouldn't casting mydict to dict be an issue? How does python deal with that? Ignore new members?

Comment: @eugeney http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy If d contains many kvps, wouldn't dict(d) be a very expensive operation? Is "dict(d)" equivalent to "d as dict"?

Comment: @Ryan: `d as dict` is not valid syntax. Depending on the size of `d`, `dict(d)` might be expensive, but as I said you don't need copying - just use the instance of  the subclass and it should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm sorta busy with the server code at the moment, and will try mydict with JsonProperty after I'm finished, then I'll get back with the result.

Comment: Okay I've tested it. I set the JsonProperty to **mydict** and put() it in the datastore. However, after fetching it back, I printed the type() NDB returned, which showed up as a **dict**. (Also, the keys in the fetched dict turned from str to unicode.)

Answer (score 0):

Python is not type safe. So the values stored in a dictionary can be of any type. One way to prevent values of other types to be added to the dictionary is to define a function which adds the data only if the type matches. Then only use this function to append to the dictionary.

```
def gain_gold(playername, amount):
    if isinstance(amount, int):
        playerdb[playername] = amount
    else:
       raise Exception('invalid type')
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating this for Python >3.7. Python does not have type enforcements since it's a dynamically typed language and type enforcements can only happen in static languages like C++. Nonetheless, it has provided an option for type hinting. Don't mistake this for the run time execution to throw errors but at least the reader will know what to expect. If you want the program to throw an exception, you'll need something like what the posters have commented previously. Nonetheless, for type hinting for a dict item, you can use:

```
from typing import Dict

def fn(x) -> Dict[str,  int]:
     return {'foo': x}
```

The datatype Dict imported from typing provides context about the return statement. It tells you that this dictionary item has string key values and integer values associated with those key values.

Comment: Note that there are also static type checking tools like [mypy](https://mypy-lang.org/) and [pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) that allow you to automatically check whether you violate the type annotations.

Comment: Yes, I have been reading up on mypy. It's an additional step of course and unless you want to use it on GitHub actions for CI pipelines, it might be an overkill for most users. I have been using this for my prod env though and I agree, this is an amazing piece of addition to the python UX.