# python Dictionary Mutable Clarification

Tags: python, dictionary, mutable

I am using dictionary as argument to the function.

When i Change the values of the argument passed, it getting changed parent dictionary.i have used dict.copy() but still not effective.

How to avoid mutable in dictionary values. Need your inputs

```
>>> myDict = {'one': ['1', '2', '3']}
>>> def dictionary(dict1):
    dict2 = dict1.copy()
    dict2['one'][0] = 'one'
    print dict2


>>> dictionary(myDict)
{'one': ['one', '2', '3']}
>>> myDict
{'one': ['one', '2', '3']}
```

My intention was my parent dictionary should be changed.
Thanks,
Vignesh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy

Comment: "My intention was my parent dictionary should be changed."  That is what is happening.  Did you mean to say your intention is that it should *not* be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `deepcopy()` from the `copy` module.

```
from copy import deepcopy
myDict = {'one': ['1', '2', '3']}
def dictionary(dict1):
    dict2 = deepcopy(dict1)
    dict2['one'][0] = 'one'
    print dict2
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

> ```
> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `deepcopy` from `copy` module like this example:

```
from copy import deepcopy

myDict = {'one': ['1', '2', '3']}

def dictionary(dict1):
    dict2 = deepcopy(dict1)
    dict2['one'][0] = 'one'
    print  dict2

dictionary(myDict)
print(myDict)
```

Output:

```
dict2 {'one': ['one', '2', '3']}
myDict {'one': ['1', '2', '3']}
```