# python-requests automatically adds http header

Tags: python, python-requests

```
def __init__(self):
   self.headers={'Accept':'application/json'}

def req1(self):
   headers=self.headers
   headers['bla']='bla'
   headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
   r=requests.post(url,headers=headers)

def req2(self):
   headers=self.headers
   headers['bla']='bla'
   r=requests.post(url + "/test1",headers=headers)
```

For some reason, when I execute those functions in this order:

```
   req1()
   req2()
```

'Content-Type' header is also sent in `req2()`.

When I execute those functions in the reverse order:

```
   req2()
   req1()
```

'Content-Type' header is only sent in `req1()`.

What might be the reason for that to happen? Maybe requests adds `Content-Type` header without asking?

For now I'm fixing the problem like so:

```
def req2():
   headers=self.headers
   headers['bla']='bla'
   del headers['Content-Type']
   r=requests.post(url + "/test1",headers=headers)
```

I'm looking for a better solution. Can someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

When you are assigning `headers` to `self.headers`, *you are not actually copying the dictionary*, you are just *creating an another reference*. Then, when you update `headers`, `self.headers` is updated cause both point to the same exact object.

If you need to actually copy a dictionary, there are different ways, please refer to:

- [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)