# Dictionary does not update properly when adding another dictionary as a value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to store dictionaries in one master dictionary, as a way to store the history of variables, so that they can be accessed later, if need be.

I define the dictionaries as such:

```
self.current = {}
self.version = {}
```

`self.current` will store two key/value pairs that will map the words `nodes` to a current nodes SQL table and the word `edges` to a current edges SQL table.

As the program iterates through, it makes new tables to represent the edges and nodes in the system, and so I would like to store `self.current` itself as a value in `self.version`, such that a `time` variable can access the state of the system at any past time step.

For example, if there are 10 iterations in total, than `self.current['nodes']` should return `'dhn_vertices_pgr9'` and `self.current['edges']` should return `'dhn9'`

I am doing this like this:

```
self.version[time] = self.current
```

At the end of each iteration.  Howevever, every single time, the `self.version` table has the most recent dictionary mapped to every single time step:

With print statements:

```
print('iteration {0}, current nodes = {1}'.format(time, self.current['nodes']))
print('iteration {0}, current edges = {1}'.format(time, self.current['edges']))
print('iteration {0}, time = {1}'.format(time, time))
print('iteration {0}, self.current = {1}'.format(time, self.current))
self.version[time] = self.current
print('iteration {0}, self.version = {1}\n'.format(time, self.version))
```

Shows in the console:

```
iteration 0, current nodes = dhn_0_vertices_pgr
iteration 0, current edges = dhn_0
iteration 0, time = 0
iteration 0, self.current = {'edges': 'dhn_0', 'nodes': 'dhn_0_vertices_pgr'}
iteration 0, self.version = {0: {'edges': 'dhn_0', 'nodes': 'dhn_0_vertices_pgr'}}

iteration 1, current nodes = dhn_1_vertices_pgr
iteration 1, current edges = dhn_1
iteration 1, time = 1
iteration 1, self.current = {'edges': 'dhn_1', 'nodes': 'dhn_1_vertices_pgr'}
iteration 1, self.version = {0: {'edges': 'dhn_1', 'nodes': 'dhn_1_vertices_pgr'}, 1: {'edges': 'dhn_1', 'nodes': 'dhn_1_vertices_pgr'}}

iteration 2, current nodes = dhn_2_vertices_pgr
iteration 2, current edges = dhn_2
iteration 2, time = 2
iteration 2, self.current = {'edges': 'dhn_2', 'nodes': 'dhn_2_vertices_pgr'}
iteration 2, self.version = {0: {'edges': 'dhn_2', 'nodes': 'dhn_2_vertices_pgr'}, 1: {'edges': 'dhn_2', 'nodes': 'dhn_2_vertices_pgr'}, 2: {'edges': 'dhn_2', 'nodes': 'dhn_2_vertices_pgr'}}

iteration 3, current nodes = dhn_3_vertices_pgr
iteration 3, current edges = dhn_3
iteration 3, time = 3
iteration 3, self.current = {'edges': 'dhn_3', 'nodes': 'dhn_3_vertices_pgr'}
iteration 3, self.version = {0: {'edges': 'dhn_3', 'nodes': 'dhn_3_vertices_pgr'}, 1: {'edges': 'dhn_3', 'nodes': 'dhn_3_vertices_pgr'}, 2: {'edges': 'dhn_3', 'nodes': 'dhn_3_vertices_pgr'}, 3: {'edges': 'dhn_3', 'nodes': 'dhn_3_vertices_pgr'}}
```

As you can see, every value in `self.version` is just the latest entry.

But what does not make sense to me, is that if I simply save both entries as a tuple like so:

```
self.version[time] = (self.current['edges'], self.current['nodes'])
```

And again with print statements:

```
print('iteration {0}, current nodes = {1}'.format(time, self.current['nodes']))
print('iteration {0}, current edges = {1}'.format(time, self.current['edges']))
print('iteration {0}, time = {1}'.format(time, time))
print('iteration {0}, self.current = {1}'.format(time, self.current))
self.version[time] = (self.current['edges'], self.current['nodes'])
print('iteration {0}, self.version = {1}\n'.format(time, self.version))
```

Gives the console output:

```
iteration 0, current nodes = dhn_0_vertices_pgr
iteration 0, current edges = dhn_0
iteration 0, time = 0
iteration 0, self.current = {'edges': 'dhn_0', 'nodes': 'dhn_0_vertices_pgr'}
iteration 0, self.version = {0: ('dhn_0', 'dhn_0_vertices_pgr')}

iteration 1, current nodes = dhn_1_vertices_pgr
iteration 1, current edges = dhn_1
iteration 1, time = 1
iteration 1, self.current = {'edges': 'dhn_1', 'nodes': 'dhn_1_vertices_pgr'}
iteration 1, self.version = {0: ('dhn_0', 'dhn_0_vertices_pgr'), 1: ('dhn_1', 'dhn_1_vertices_pgr')}

iteration 2, current nodes = dhn_2_vertices_pgr
iteration 2, current edges = dhn_2
iteration 2, time = 2
iteration 2, self.current = {'edges': 'dhn_2', 'nodes': 'dhn_2_vertices_pgr'}
iteration 2, self.version = {0: ('dhn_0', 'dhn_0_vertices_pgr'), 1: ('dhn_1', 'dhn_1_vertices_pgr'), 2: ('dhn_2', 'dhn_2_vertices_pgr')}

iteration 3, current nodes = dhn_3_vertices_pgr
iteration 3, current edges = dhn_3
iteration 3, time = 3
iteration 3, self.current = {'edges': 'dhn_3', 'nodes': 'dhn_3_vertices_pgr'}
iteration 3, self.version = {0: ('dhn_0', 'dhn_0_vertices_pgr'), 1: ('dhn_1', 'dhn_1_vertices_pgr'), 2: ('dhn_2', 'dhn_2_vertices_pgr'), 3: ('dhn_3', 'dhn_3_vertices_pgr')}
```

As you can see, time step 1 now actually maps to the table names as they were in time step 1, time step 2 maps to the table names as in time step 2, table names in 3 to time step 3, etc...

So why is it that doing this in a dictionary causes it to fail, when doing it with tuples works perfectly fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign

```
self.version[time] = (self.current)
```

You do not assign the value of the dict, but a reference to the same dict. Consider the following example:

```
dictA = {}
dictB = {}
dictA = dictB
dictB['foo'] = 'bar'
print(dictA) //{'foo': 'bar'}
print(dictB) //{'foo': 'bar'}
```

In this example, when you assign `dictA = dictB` you point both `dictA` and `dictB` to the same object. So changing `dictB` will also change `dictA` (and the opposite) To fix this, you instead want to copy the *value* of `dictB` (and not the reference). And you do this by `dict(dictB)` according to:

```
dictA = {}
dictB = {}
dictA = dict(dictB) //the value of dictB is now copied, not the reference
dictB['foo'] = 'bar'
print(dictA) //{}
print(dictB) //{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Back to your example: Change `self.current` will also affect `self.version`. So to fix this change to:

```
self.version[time] = dict(self.current)
```

See [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

Comment: thank you, this was exactly what i needed.  i have been puzzling over this for the greater part of an hour, i knew it had to be something simple like this.