# String by value; Dictionary by reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm coming from C, learning Python. In Python (3.5.2), it seems that assignment of one data type to another of the same type is sometimes done by value and sometimes by reference.

For example, strings are assigned by value:

```
>>> str1 = "hello"
>>> str2 = str1
>>> print(str1, str2)
hello hello
>>> str2 = "goodbye"
>>> print(str1, str2)
hello goodbye
```

This is the behavior I expect.  However, it works differently with dictionaries:

```
>>> dict1 = {'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}
>>> dict2 = dict1
>>> print(dict1, dict2)
{'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1'} {'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1'}
>>> dict2['key1'] = 'newval'
>>> print(dict1, dict2)
{'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'newval'} {'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'newval'}
```

Notice that both `dict1` *and* `dict2` were changed.  Similarly, if I add a key/value pair to either of the dictionaries it will appear in both. **Argh!**

(sorry, that was my C-background speaking) :)

How am I to know which behavior to expect for any given variable type?  Is there a method to this madness or will I simply need to remember arbitrary rules?

P.S. I realize I can get my expected behavior by using `dict2 = dict(dict1)`.

---

The "possible duplicate" contains good info on *how* to do it, but I'm interested in *why* I have to. The answers to this question are already very helpful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

Comment: to copy a dictionary use new_dict = dict(old_dict) otherwise they will reference the same dict.

Comment: There's a difference between `var = ...` and `var[...] = ...`. The first is reassigning the variable to point to a different object (as is the case with `str2 = "goodbye"`). The second is an action on the object: `dict2.__setitem__('key1', 'newval')`.

Comment: Have a quick [guide](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) to how assignment and variables work in Python. Neither "by value" nor "by reference" is an accurate description.

Comment: For a brief summary (with nice diagrams) of the key information in the link user2357112 posted, please see [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, everything is by reference; This is different from C, variable is not a box. The assignment is actually a binding.

```
str1 = "hello"
str2 = str1
```

Both `str1` and `str2` reference to "hello", <strike>but string in Python is immutable, so</strike> modifying `str2`, would creating a new binding, and hence do not affect the value of `str1`

```
str2 = "hack"
# here str1 will still reference to "hello" object
```

Dict works the same:

```
d1 = {"name": "Tom"}
d2 = d1
```

`d2` and `d1` will reference the same object. If change `d2` to a new value do not affect the value of `d1`; But instead, if we only modify `d2` in place, like `d2['age'] = 20`, the value of `d1` would be changed since they share the same object.

```
d2 = {"name": "Hack"}
# the value of d1 does not change
```

Luciano Ramalho summarized it in **Fluent Python**, Chapter 8, **Variables Are Not Boxes** section

> To understand an assignment in Python, always read the righthand side first: that’s where the object is created or retrieved. After that, the variable on the left is bound to the object, like a label stuck to it. Just forget about the boxes.

Comment: `but string in Python is immutable, so modify str2 (create a new binding) will not affect the value of str1`. This is not a sensible conclusion. For instance, bytearray is mutable, but assigning a bytearray to `str2` would still not mutate the old value. @bitsmack is assuming that assignment does something, like copying values in C. That is not the case.

Comment: @phihag: Bytestrings are also immutable; maybe you meant bytearrays or something.

Comment: Thank you! This explanation and the examples are just what I was looking for.  Yay! Not arbitrary :)

Answer (score 2):

You are misinterpreting how assignments work. In Python, assignment (`=`) sets the name on the left side to the value on the right side.

This is roughly equivalent to assigning pointers in C, where the same behavior exists:

```
char* str1 = "hello";
char* str2 = str1;
str2 = "world";
printf("%s %s", str1, str2); // prints "hello world"
```

If you want to create a copy of a value in Python, call a function that does that or use a comprehension to define a new version. For instance, to copy a dictionary, the following work:

```
dict2 = dict(dict1)          # dict constructor (shallow copy)
dict2 = copy.copy(dict1)     # shallow copy
dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1) # deep copy
dict2 = {k: v for k, v in dict1.items()} # dict comprehension

# or, in multiple lines ...
dict2 = {} # literal: create a brand-new dict, equivalent to dict()
for k, v in dict1.items():
    dict2[k] = v
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I need to look up the difference between deep and shallow copies :)