# Set variable with .get() method induces a global link between variable and dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not sure if I am going crazy here. I have numerical data stored in a dictionary which I will run a function to alter that data. Before I do this, I want to temporarily store the data to compare with the next iteration. In this example, `dictionary` is the dictionary in question and `update_data` is a function which manipulates the values of the object `'data'` in the dictionary.

example:

```
for i in range(n_iterations):
       old_data           = dictionary.get('data')
       #call function which manipulates data
       dictionary['data'] = update_data(dictionary) 
       diff = max(dictionary['data']-old_data)
```

when I compare the old and new, they are the same through each iteration. `diff` is always `0` and when I compare them visually, it seems that when I set `old_data`, I am implying a global link between the variable `old_data` and the dictionary value.

Can someone please clarify the linkages between the dictionary object and the variable in the above example? Also, can someone suggest a workaround to storing the object before it is manipulated? Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Honestly, I don't follow you here... What, *exactly* is `dictionary.get('data')` returning, you say it is "numerical" data, but is it actually some kind of container which you mutate in `update_data`?

Comment: depends what `update_data` actually does. I'm guessing it modifies the object in the dictionary, rather than creating a new object and replacing the value in the dictionary. In which case, since `old_data` is just a reference to the same object, yes, they are "linked".

Comment: Yep, this is it. Is there a way to simply define a variable as the object in its current state?

Comment: If you're trying to break links, you could try `copy.deepcopy` (or `copy.copy` if you don't need deep copying).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I believe this is the solution to my problem.

Comment: @Blorgbeard answered my ambiguous question. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

In the example, what I intended to do was to make an independent copy of the dictionary. What python did was create a new reference to that dictionary. To preserve independence, as in the comments by @ShadowRanger and in the link above, you need to make an explicit copy of the dictionary and its values. Following the example in the question, this can be achieved with

```
import copy

old_data = copy.deepcopy(dictionary)['data']
```

now `old_data` is an independent 'copy' of the values in `dictionary['data']`.