# Update value of specific key in a dictionary, contained in a list for one dictionary in the list raher than for all dictionaries in the list

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, python-3.5

I have the following variables:

- A list called `word_frequencies` that has the same dictionary with all values 0, at each position of the list.
- A list called `all_preprocessed_articles` that has a vector that contains all the words from a particular article, at each position of the list. (Thus, `len(word_frequencies) = len(all_preprocessed_articles)`)

The dictionary is a set of all the words in all the articles.

I have Initialised the list item, with all the dictionary items as follows:

```
word_frequencies = []

for word in vocab:
    temp_frequency_dict.update({word:0})

for i in range(0, num_articles): 
    word_frequencies.append(temp_frequency_dict)
```

With the following code, I am aiming to iterate through each vector i in `all_preprocessed_articles` and changing the dictionary i in the `word_frequencies` list for that word, by adding 1 to the value of that particular word (key).

```
for i in range(0, num_articles):
    current_article = all_preprocessed_articles[i]
    for word in current_article:
        word_frequencies[i][word] += 1
```

What I expect as output is that each dictionary in `word_frequencies` shows the frequencies for each word in that specific article. However, what it outputs is the same dictionary at each position in `word_frequencies`.

What can I do to so that the output is a list with `i` dictionaries in which each dictionary shows the occurrences per word in the corresponding article?

Comment: "'word_frequencies' that has the same dictionary with all values 0"- i think this is your mistake, initiate these as *different* dictionaries, likely you have many references to the *same* dictionary instead; please update to a clear minimal reproducible example too

Comment: I have initiated it as:

    for i in range(0, num_articles):
    word_frequencies.append(temp_frequency_dict)

Where 'temp_frequency_dict' is a single dictionary. Is that the mistake, you mean?

Comment: Try `for i in range(0, num_articles): word_frequencies.append(dict(temp_frequency_dict))`

Comment: This is my first question on Stackoverflow. What do you mean by a 'minimal reproducible example'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works!

Comment: you're welcome , read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy and consider marking your question as a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)