# Increment id during loop in list of collections

Tags: python, list, loops

I try to increment a list at each iteration of a loop :

```
ads = []
page = {}
page['titre'] = "Title here"
page['nombre_pages'] = 396

i = 1 
total = 3

while i <= total:
    print(i)
    page['id'] = i
    ads.append(page)
    i += 1
```

this return

```
[{'titre': 'Title here', 'nombre_pages': 396, 'id': 3}, {'titre': 'Title here', 'nombre_pages': 396, 'id': 3}, {'titre': 'Title here', 'nombre_pages': 396, 'id': 3}]
```

I don't understand why the same id 3 times and not id:1, id:2, id:3

When print page['id'] is ok (increment), ads.append(page['id']) is available too.

Can you help ?

Thanks

Comment: That's not an array, that's a list.

Comment: you need to make a copy

Comment: You're modifying and appending the same `page` dict each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're only creating a single "page" object, i.e. by doing:

page = {}

and referring to it from several index locations in `ads`.  you probably want to be doing something closer to:

```
ads = []

i = 1 
total = 3

while i <= total:
    print(i)
    page = {}
    page['titre'] = "Title here"
    page['nombre_pages'] = 396
    page['id'] = i
    ads.append(page)
    i += 1
```

or slightly more idiomatically:

```
ads = []
total = 3
for i in range(total):
    ads.append({
        'nombre_pages': 396,
        'titre': "Title here",
        'id': i,
    })
```