# zeep objects stored in list keep getting overwritten

Tags: python-2.7, zeep

I am trying to append many variables that are `zeep` objects to a list. However, when I print out the list at the end, each variable in the list has the same data.

I have tried isolating when the variable gets overwritten, and it's happening when I put a new value into the variable with the same name, but I do this after I append the variable to the list. So I am confused as to why this is happening. I've tried to use different variable names, but it results in the same problem.

```
def create_json_list(json_template):
    newVar = json_template
    newVar['name'] = unique_name
    list.append(newVar)

    newVar = json_template
    newVar['name'] = unique_name2
    list.append(newVar)


    print(list[0]['name'])
    print(list[1]['name'])
# At this point, the same name gets printed twice
```

Comment: What is the type and value of `json_template`? Please use the [edit] link below your post to update it with additional info.

Comment: I just learned that it's a zeep object, not just plain json, i don't know if that makes a big difference, i dont even know what a zeep object is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the same object to the list multiple times. If you notice, the template is getting modified:

```
import json

template = {
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": "two"
}

json_list = list()

def create_json_list(json_template):
    newVar = json_template
    newVar['name'] = "unique_name"
    json_list.append(newVar)

    newVar = json_template
    newVar['name'] = 'another_unique_name'
    json_list.append(newVar)

    print(json.dumps(json_template, indent=4))

create_json_list(template)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "field2": "two", 
    "field1": 1, 
    "name": "another_unique_name"
}
```

You need to create a new template for each entry:

```
newVar = dict(json_template)
```

From the [documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

```
Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
bindings between a target and an object.
```

If you want to copy an object, you need to let Python know. In the case of a `dict`, you can just use the constructor as shown above.

For a `zeep` object, you should be able to use a [factory](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/datastructures.html#using-factories):

```
factory = client.type_factory('ns0')
newVar = factory.JsonTemplate({"field1": 1, "field2": "two"})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Why/how is it that the json_template is getting modified if I'm never assigning anything to it?

Comment: You can think of `newVar = json_template` as telling Python that you want to use a new name to refer to `json_template`. Any modification of `newVar` is a modification of `json_template`. You need to make a new copy of `json_template` every time you need one.

Comment: Okay amazing it works. A follow up, do you know if there is way to make a copy of a zeep object by chance? Right now i have to convert from zeep to dict to then be able to make copies, but I'd prefer if i could make a copy from the zeep itself.

Comment: Have a look at [Using factories](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/datastructures.html#using-factories) in the [zeep documentation](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html).