# Python Duplicate Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am unable to create a "duplicate" dictionary in the program

below is the sample code

```
dict1={'name':'rahul',age:30}
```

i need to create a dictionary with two entries.

Comment: What do you mean with "duplicate"?

Comment: `dict2 = dict(dict1)`? or https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy . what have you tried?

Comment: @sudarshang is `age` a variable referencing a string? I think you might want to put ticks around the word "age". Might be helpful too if you could say what the error message is that you're seeing.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, there are two ways to create copies :

- Shallow copy
- Deep copy

In order to make these copy, you can use the `copy` module.
For Example:

```
import copy 

dict1={'name':'rahul', 'age': 30}   

# Shallow copy   
dict2 = copy.copy(dict1)  

# Deep Copy  
dict3 = copy.deepcopy(dict1)
```

If you don't know the difference between `shallow copy` and `deep copy` please check this very good article: https://docs.roguewave.com/sourcepro/11.1/html/toolsug/6-4.html

I find this image essential in understanding the concept:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the quotes around `age`:

```
dict1={'name':'rahul', 'age':30}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean copying a dictionary?
You have two options:

1. Shallow Copy
2. Deep Copy

Check this link:
https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-copy-a-dictionary-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy/

Answer (score 1):

In python dictionary both  key and value should be Enclosed with double Quotes or Single Quotes if the value is a string.

You can't assign a value to a key like assigning value  to a variable

Example:

In dictionary you should assign as 'age':30

If 'age' is a variable that you are declaring outside the dictionary then you can assign as

age = 30

Coming back to your Question did you mean copying a dictionary or just create a duplicate like this

`dict1={'name':'rahul','age':30}
dict2={'name':'rahul','age':30}
print(dict1)
print(dict2)`

if you need to know how to copy a dictionary refer this article
https://www.science-emergence.com/Articles/How-to-copy-a-dictionary-in-python-/