# Save .txt file in a dict with specific format

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have a problem by reading my .txt file and save it in dict. 
This is my following code:

```
 def __init__(self, folder_path):
    os.chdir(folder_path)
    self._path = folder_path
    self._data = {}
    _files = glob.glob('*.txt')
    _temp = {}
    for dat in _files:
        _temp.clear()
        with open(dat,"r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
            for item in f:
                if item != '\n':
                    custom = (item.strip('\n').split('='))
                    _temp[custom[0]] = custom[1]
                    self._data[dat] = _temp
    print(self._data)
```

And this is the output:

```
{'RC0603FR-07100KL.txt': {'count': '20', 'value': 'TPS73033', 'package': 'SOT-23-5'}, 
'RC0805FR-07100KL.txt': {'count': '20', 'value': 'TPS73033', 'package': 'SOT-23-5'}, 
'TPS73033DBVT.txt': {'count': '20', 'value': 'TPS73033', 'package': 'SOT-23-5'}}
```

The exactly problem is, that the last value override the all other one.
For ex. this is how it should look like:

```
{'RC0603FR-07100KL.txt': {'count': '100', 'value': '100k', 'package': 'Chip'}, 
'RC0805FR-07100KL.txt': {'count': '50', 'value': '10n', 'package': 'Cap'}, 
'TPS73033DBVT.txt': {'count': '20', 'value': 'TPS73033', 'package': 'SOT-23-5'}}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

A sample of .txt file:

```
count=50
value=100k
unit=Ohm
package=0603
description=Chip Resistor
supplier=Digikey
supplierpartnumber=311-100KHRCT-ND
price=0.009
currency=CHF
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the text files?

Comment: Your problem is that you are assigning the same dict `_temp` to all of the `self._data`. You need to make a copy of the dict for each `self._data` or initialise the dicts and assign values to it. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

Comment: @jordanm yes, i add one sample the other ones look like this one but with other values for count,unit etc.

Comment: @hadik hmm... i dont get it really but i will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the dict. Replace `self._data[dat] = _temp` by `self._data[dat] = _temp.copy()`

Check this example:

```
data = [
    {'a':1, 'b':1},
    {'a':2, 'b':2},
]
copieddata = []
temp = {}
for d in data:
    temp.clear()
    for k, v in d.items():
        temp[k] = v
    copieddata.append(temp)
```

This will have `copieddata` as:

```
[{'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2}]
```

Because, you are basically using the same variable `temp` and assign it to different elements of the list (`copieddata`). But what you want is that you want to create different `dict` and assign it to elements of the list, hence you need to copy the `temp` variable. That ensures new dict is created and not the same one is reused for all the elements of the list (`copieddata`). 
Below I used `.copy()` to add to the list, and works as expected.

```
data = [
    {'a':1, 'b':1},
    {'a':2, 'b':2},
]
copieddata = []
temp = {}
for d in data:
    temp.clear()
    for k, v in d.items():
        temp[k] = v
    copieddata.append(temp.copy())
```

Copied data is now :

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2}]
```

Comment: @srky great that it works. [Check this to read more on copying the python objects or just assigning or referencing it.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)