# Why does dict.pop() here remove the value from two dictonaries while specifing only one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am writing a program in which I need to iterate through many long dictionaries, so I thought I could remove unneeded values from it, to save on some runtime. Here is a minimal working example with lacking context:

```
years = {0: 2019, 1: 2020, 2: 2021}


def iterate_years():
    for i in years:
        temp_years = years
        print("years:", years)
        print("temp_years:", temp_years)
        temp_years.pop(i)
        minimum = min(temp_years)
        maximum = max(temp_years)
        print("temp_years:", years)
        print("years:", years)


iterate_years()
```

When I run this it returns a runtime error because the size f the dictionary changed while iteration. As you can see through the example the line `temp_years.pop(i)` seems to pop the key-value pair `i` in temp_years, as specified but also in `years`.
Why does this happen? I am not very experienced but `years` is never assigned to `temp_years` after the `pop()` so the value for `years` should stay like they were specified in the first line.

Comment: They point to the same location in memory. Do `temp_years = years.copy()` instead.

Comment: See above answer, same applies to dict

Comment: Yes, thank you this solved it! I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that temp_years and years are pointing to the same object in memory (reference), you can check it comparing the id of both variables:

```py
>>> id(temp_years) == id(years)
>>> True
```

If you want a copy, you have to create a new dict with `temp_years = years.copy()`. But if you have nested objects in the dictionary, you will have to do a [deep copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html), because dict.copy() only does a [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

```py
>>> import copy
>>> temp_years = copy.deepcopy(years)
>>> id(temp_years)
140641196228824
>>> id(years)
140641197662072
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy when you create the dict `temp_years` otherwise it will just function as a pointer to the original object (`years`). That's why the changes you're making to `temp_years` also change `years`. So all you need is to change that assignment line:

```
temp_years = years.copy()
```

You could also make it a deepcopy if it's a nested dict (otherwise you'll only get the top level keys):

```
import copy
temp_years = copy.deepcopy(years)
```

Check out this answer for more details: [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)