# Dictionary value is modified in two different keys instead of one

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to build a new key into my dictionary by taking another one from the same dictionary.
And I would like to change some values in that new key.

Let's look at an example:

```
# Here is a dictionary
my_dict = {'one' : {'same': 'test_1'}}

# Create a new key based on a pre-existing one in our dictionary
my_dict['two'] = my_dict['one']

# Asign a new value to that new key:
my_dict['two']['same'] = 'test_2'
```

What I expected when `print(my_dict)`:

```
{'one': {'same': 'test_1'}, 'two': {'same': 'test_2'}}
```

But here is what I got:

```
{'one': {'same': 'test_2'}, 'two': {'same': 'test_2'}}
```

My question is: why both `one` and `two` have changed? Why not just `two` like I asked?

Also if we try:

```
# Creating a dictionary but this time, fully prepared
my_dict = {'one': {'same': 'test_1'}, 'two': {'same': 'test_1'}}

# Changing a value in key two:
my_dict['two']['same'] = 'test_2'
```

We get `print(my_dict)`:

```
{'one': {'same': 'test_1'}, 'two': {'same': 'test_2'}}
```

Which this time, is the output I expected.

What's the difference between this two methods?

*Edit Answer*:

It was not working because at `my_dict['two'] = my_dict['one']` it was assigning the same reference to both keys. So if one of them is changed, all the corresponding references will change too.

To avoid this as suggested in the answers: `my_dict['two'] = my_dict['one'].copy()` will copy the key but without the reference.

More info in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2465932/10972294

This post is a duplicated, but as suggested here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265737/10972294

This post still might help for those who are not aware of the copy & reference stuff in python dictionaries.

Comment: Simple, when you perform `my_dict['two'] = my_dict['one']` then both point to the same instance by reference. So as both point to the same instance, changing that one instance through `two` will be reflected in `one`.

Comment: You need to make a copy of the dictionary by using the its `copy()` method.

Comment: It is because if this `my_dict['two'] = my_dict['one']` this creates the reference between the objects as you have assigned that value from `one` and when you change `two`, the other gets changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick in order to avoid reference issues.

```
my_dict['two'] = my_dict['one'].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of assignment using `my_dict['two'] = my_dict['one']`, you assigned the reference to the object which `my_dict['one']` was pointing to `my_dict['two']`.

Now you have two keys in the dict pointing to same object.

```
>>> my_dict = {'one' : {'same': 'test_1'}}
>>> my_dict['two'] = my_dict['one']

# You didn't just created a key, but also stored the same referrence
>>> my_dict['two']
{'same': 'test_1'}

# object pointed by my_dict['two'] is as same my_dict['one']
>>> my_dict['two'] is my_dict['one']
True
```

Hence any update in the object of any of the key will reflect for both the keys as they are referring same object.

Answer (score 0):

Python basically uses references for lists and dict. You need to unpack it using `**`

```
>>> my_dict = {'one' : {'same': 'test_1'}}
>>> my_dict['two'] = {**my_dict['one']}
>>> my_dict
{'one': {'same': 'test_1'}, 'two': {'same': 'test_1'}}
>>> my_dict["two"]["same"] = "test_2"
>>> my_dict
{'one': {'same': 'test_1'}, 'two': {'same': 'test_2'}}
```