# Python, dict. Changes also appear on the main object even though saved only on a different object?

Tags: python, dictionary, setdefault

Changes also appear on the main object even though  saved only on a different object?

```
A dict:
transportation = {"car":"ford", "coche":"fiat"}
```

```
The changes:
x = transportation.setdefault("carro", "BMW")
```

```
Output of the object where changes were stored(x):
BMW
```

```
Output of the original dict:
{"car":"ford", "coche":"fiat", "carro", "BMW"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)  The link is about `list`s not `dict`s, but the fundamental problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Dict is mutable object. Which means you are assigning a reference to the same dict. Instead try

```
x = transportation.copy().setdefault("carro", "BMW")
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

Comment: I just remembered how it works. Thank you for your contribution. With copy() method we create a copy not linked to the original but an oposed result with a simple atribution.