# Python changing variable without apparent reason

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I have a weird behaviour of Python that is probably pretty rational, but I don't understand it. look at this code here:

```
def changeDict(status):
    hotstatus = status
    for e in hotstatus:
        if hotstatus[e]:
            hotstatus[e] = "Successful"
        else:
            hotstatus[e] = "Failed"
    print(hotstatus)
    message = f"""
    Operation start: {hotstatus["operation-start"]}
    Operation stop: {hotstatus["operation-stop"]}
    """
    return message

def initalDict():
    status = {}
    status["operation-start"] = True
    status["operation-stop"] = False
    print(status)
    message = changeDict(status)
    print(message)
    print(f"This is the status: {status}")

initalDict()
```

How does this output come from this:

```
{'operation-start': True, 'operation-stop': False}
{'operation-start': 'Successful', 'operation-stop': 'Failed'}

    Operation start: Successful
    Operation stop: Failed
    
This is the status: {'operation-start': 'Successful', 'operation-stop': 'Failed'}
```

Shouldn't the last line still read True and False as the values?
I am very confused.
It would be great if someone could help me with that mystery :D.

Kind regards

Comment: `if hotstatus[e]` checks whether the value is `True` (or `False`). However, when `True`, `changeDict` replaces the `True` with `'Successful'` (and the `False` with `'Failed'`)

Answer (score 1):

In Python `dict` is mutable, so when you assign one to another variable:

```
 hotstatus = status
```

that simply creates an alias for the underlying, mutable `dict`. Modifying the `dict` aliased to by `hotstatus`, modifies the same `dict` refenced by the variable name `status`.

If you try this instead:

```
   import copy
   ... code ...
   hotstatus = copy.deepcopy(status)
```

you'll make a `copy` of the `dict` that `status` refers to (actually a deepcopy, everything will be copied so even if there's another mutable stored in that `dict` all of its contents will be copied over too) so `hotstatus` has its very own `dict` to work with.  Modifications to `hotstatus` will have no affect on what `status` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

When you send the dictionary `status` to the function `changeDict()` you are **sending the reference** to the `status` dictionary and not a copy of it.

So changing the values of `hotstatus` in `changeDict()` will change the `status` dictionary as both are referring to the same object.

You can use `hotstatus = status.copy()` to use copy of status dict.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy) will give you a clear idea behind this concept.

Comment: You should also include a way to fix op's code so it works how they want it to (just making a copy should do it)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using hotstatus = status. which makes both of them point to same memory location. so both of them will be updated when you update one dictionary.

refer this link for more info :
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `hotstatus = status` it doesn't create a copy of your dictionary input you are just changing the name, if you want to create a copy you should use `hotstatus = status.copy()`, then you will be able to edit hotstatus without changing status