# Copy items from dictionary into another dictionary based on keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list

```
list_x = ['8', '4', '5', '6', '1']
```

and a dictionary

```
dict_1 = {'0': {'ID=3': 1, 'ID=7': 1},
 '1': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=6': 2},
 '2': {'ID=7': 3, 'ID=5': 1},
 '3': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=1': 1},
 '4': {'ID=3': 3, 'ID=5': 1, 'ID=4': 1},
 '5': {'ID=5': 1, 'ID=2': 3, 'ID=4': 2, 'ID=7': 1, 'ID=8': 1},
 '6': {'ID=0': 5, 'ID=3': 7, 'ID=1': 1},
 '7': {'ID=1': 1, 'ID=8': 1, 'ID=7': 1},
 '8': {'ID=6': 2, 'ID=0': 2, 'ID=2': 2}}
```

and I want to create a new dictionary dict_2 in which all items of dict_1 are stored that have a key that exists in list_x. How can I do that? I had trouble doing it with two nested for loops since I could access the keys but I could not copy the entire item.

Comment: You can use `dict_2 = {k: v for k, v in dict_1.items() if k in list_x}`

Comment: Can there be a value in ```list_x``` that is not a key of ```dict_1``` ?

Comment: `{k: dict_1[k] for k in list_x}`

Comment: @Metapod No, that cannot be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for this pretty easily:

```
itemgetter(*list_x)(dict_1)
```

All code below:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list_x = ['8', '4', '5', '6', '1']
dict_1 = {'0': {'ID=3': 1, 'ID=7': 1},
 '1': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=6': 2},
 '2': {'ID=7': 3, 'ID=5': 1},
 '3': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=1': 1},
 '4': {'ID=3': 3, 'ID=5': 1, 'ID=4': 1},
 '5': {'ID=5': 1, 'ID=2': 3, 'ID=4': 2, 'ID=7': 1, 'ID=8': 1},
 '6': {'ID=0': 5, 'ID=3': 7, 'ID=1': 1},
 '7': {'ID=1': 1, 'ID=8': 1, 'ID=7': 1},
 '8': {'ID=6': 2, 'ID=0': 2, 'ID=2': 2}}
 
print(dict(zip(list_x, (itemgetter(*list_x)(dict_1)))))
```

---

```
{'8': {'ID=6': 2, 'ID=0': 2, 'ID=2': 2},
 '4': {'ID=3': 3, 'ID=5': 1, 'ID=4': 1},
 '5': {'ID=5': 1, 'ID=2': 3, 'ID=4': 2, 'ID=7': 1, 'ID=8': 1},
 '6': {'ID=0': 5, 'ID=3': 7, 'ID=1': 1},
 '1': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=6': 2}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
list_x = ['8', '4', '5', '6', '1']


dict_1 = {'0': {'ID=3': 1, 'ID=7': 1},
 '1': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=6': 2},
 '2': {'ID=7': 3, 'ID=5': 1},
 '3': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=1': 1},
 '4': {'ID=3': 3, 'ID=5': 1, 'ID=4': 1},
 '5': {'ID=5': 1, 'ID=2': 3, 'ID=4': 2, 'ID=7': 1, 'ID=8': 1},
 '6': {'ID=0': 5, 'ID=3': 7, 'ID=1': 1},
 '7': {'ID=1': 1, 'ID=8': 1, 'ID=7': 1},
 '8': {'ID=6': 2, 'ID=0': 2, 'ID=2': 2}}
d={k:dict_1.get(k).copy() for k in list_x if k in dict_1}
print(d)
```

Comment: @metapod, thanks. Added the control statement

Comment: If any value from ```dict_1``` is changed, it will be changed in ```dict_2```too ! You should get the nested dict by ```copy```: ```k:dict_1.get(k).copy()```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use a dictionary comprehension, as so:

```py
dict_2 = {k: v for k, v in dict_1.items() if k in list_x}
```

A note should be made, however, on the linking of the two dicts since they are collections which contain mutable items. If you want a completely separate result (when one changes the other stays the same) you can use `deepcopy` from the `copy` module:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

list_x = ['8', '4', '5', '6', '1']

dict_1 = {'0': {'ID=3': 1, 'ID=7': 1},
 '1': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=6': 2},
 '2': {'ID=7': 3, 'ID=5': 1},
 '3': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=1': 1},
 '4': {'ID=3': 3, 'ID=5': 1, 'ID=4': 1},
 '5': {'ID=5': 1, 'ID=2': 3, 'ID=4': 2, 'ID=7': 1, 'ID=8': 1},
 '6': {'ID=0': 5, 'ID=3': 7, 'ID=1': 1},
 '7': {'ID=1': 1, 'ID=8': 1, 'ID=7': 1},
 '8': {'ID=6': 2, 'ID=0': 2, 'ID=2': 2}}

dict_2 = {k: v for k, v in deepcopy(dict_1).items() if k in list_x}
```

Now when doing an assignment such as `dict_1['4']['ID=3'] = 1000`, `dict_2` will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dict_1 = {'0': {'ID=3': 1, 'ID=7': 1},
 '1': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=6': 2},
 '2': {'ID=7': 3, 'ID=5': 1},
 '3': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=1': 1},
 '4': {'ID=3': 3, 'ID=5': 1, 'ID=4': 1},
 '5': {'ID=5': 1, 'ID=2': 3, 'ID=4': 2, 'ID=7': 1, 'ID=8': 1},
 '6': {'ID=0': 5, 'ID=3': 7, 'ID=1': 1},
 '7': {'ID=1': 1, 'ID=8': 1, 'ID=7': 1},
 '8': {'ID=6': 2, 'ID=0': 2, 'ID=2': 2}}
 

list_x = ['8', '4', '5', '6', '1']
 
dict_2 = {}
for key, value in dict_1.items():
    if key in list_x:
        dict_2[key] = dict_1[key].copy()
         
         
print(dict_2)
```

Verify the above output.

See how to iterate dictionary items from [here](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#:%7E:text=5.6.%20Looping%20Techniques%C2%B6)

To understand why `copy()` is used, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy) post.

Comment: As dicts are mutable, you should use ```copy```: ```dict_2[key] = dict_1[key].copy()```. Otherwise, changing ```dict_1``` will change ```dict_2``` too

Comment: not in the above answer. you can verify it.

Comment: I did: ```list_x = ['1']; dict_1['1']['ID=6'] = 456 ;print(dict_2); >> {'1': {'ID=7': 2, 'ID=6': 456}} ``` Because ```dict_1[X]``` is a dict. (I didn't mention the part with your algorithm, too lazy :) But it's of course done before the re-assignation)