# python - Update default values in dictionary from dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

From a `dataframe`, I build a `dictionary` that has as `keys` each *distinct* value from a given column.
The *value* of each *key* is a *nested dictionary*, being the *key* the *distinct* values from another column.
The *Values* in the *nested dictionary* will be updated by iterating a *dataframe* (third column).

**Example**:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['computer',1, 10]
       ,['computer',2,20]
       ,['computer',4, 40]
       ,['laptop',1, 100]
       ,['laptop',3, 30]
       ,['printer',2, 200]
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Product','id', 'qtt'])
print (df)
```

| Product | id | qtt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| computer | 1 | 10 |
| computer | 2 | 20 |
| computer | 4 | 40 |
| laptop | 1 | 100 |
| laptop | 3 | 30 |
| printer | 2 | 200 |

```
kdf_key_dic = {key: None for key in df['id'].unique().tolist()}

product_key_dic = {key: kdf_key_dic for key in df['Product'].unique().tolist()}

print ("product_key_dic: ", product_key_dic)
```

```
  product_key_dic:  {
   'computer': {1: None, 2: None, 4: None, 3: None}, 
   'laptop': {1: None, 2: None, 4: None, 3: None}, 
   'printer': {1: None, 2: None, 4: None, 3: None}
}
```

Now I'd like to update the `product_key_dic` dictionary, but I can't get it right, it always uses the same key-dict for each key in the main dictionary!

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  product_key_dic[row['Product']].update({row['id']:row['qtt']})

print("\n product_key_dic:\n", product_key_dic)
```

**I get:**

```
 product_key_dic:
 { 'computer': {1: 100, 2: 200, 4: 40, 3: 30}, 
   'laptop': {1: 100, 2: 200, 4: 40, 3: 30}, 
   'printer': {1: 100, 2: 200, 4: 40, 3: 30}
 }
```

**I expect:**

```
 { 'computer': {1: 10, 2: 20, 4: 40, 3: None}, 
   'laptop':  {1: 100, 2: None, 4: None, 3: 30}, 
   'printer': {1: None, 2: 200, 4: None, 3: None}
 }
```

I can't understand the problem, somehow it's like each key has the nested dictoinary..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try a different approach creating a [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) based on the unique values from Product and Id then reshaping so we can call [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) directly:

```
cols = ['Product', 'id']

product_key_dic = (
    df.set_index(cols).reindex(
        pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
            [df[col].unique() for col in cols],
            names=cols
        )
    )  # Reindex to ensure all pairs are present in the DF
        .replace({np.nan: None})  # Replace nan with None
        .unstack('Product')  # Create Columns from Product
        .droplevel(0, axis=1)  # Remove qtt from column MultiIndex
        .to_dict()
)
```

`product_key_dic`:

```
{
    'computer': {1: 10.0, 2: 20.0, 3: None, 4: 40.0},
    'laptop': {1: 100.0, 2: None, 3: 30.0, 4: None},
    'printer': {1: None, 2: 200.0, 3: None, 4: None}
}
```

---

Methods Used:

1. [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
2. [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)
3. [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)
4. [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)
5. [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)
6. [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)
7. [`DataFrame.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html)
8. [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Setup and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [['computer', 1, 10], ['computer', 2, 20], ['computer', 4, 40],
        ['laptop', 1, 100], ['laptop', 3, 30], ['printer', 2, 200]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Product', 'id', 'qtt'])
```

---

The initial solution *could* be modified by adding a `copy` call to the dictionary in the comprehension to make them separate dictionaries rather than multiple references to the same one ([How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2465921/15497888)). However, iterating over DataFrames is discouraged ([Does pandas iterrows have performance issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24870953/15497888)):

```
kdf_key_dic = {key: None for key in df['id'].unique().tolist()}

product_key_dic = {key: kdf_key_dic.copy()
                   for key in df['Product'].unique().tolist()}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    product_key_dic[row['Product']].update({row['id']: row['qtt']})
```

```
product_key_dic:
{
    'computer': {1: 10.0, 2: 20.0, 3: None, 4: 40.0},
    'laptop': {1: 100.0, 2: None, 3: 30.0, 4: None},
    'printer': {1: None, 2: 200.0, 3: None, 4: None}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are reusing same dict object. Let's take these two statements.

```
kdf_key_dic = {key: None for key in df['id'].unique().tolist()}
product_key_dic = {key: kdf_key_dic for key in df['Product'].unique().tolist()}
```

You are passing `kdf_key_dic` as value(in the second statement) which is same object in each iteration.

So instead of this you can pass a copy of `kdf_key_dic` while constructing `product_key_dic`

```
product_key_dic = {key: kdf_key_dic.copy() for key in df['Product'].unique().tolist()}
```