# Save dictionary in a variable python

Tags: python, dictionary, return-value

I have a dictionary and I want to work with it and make some changes to it with my function. After the changes I want to save the dictionary in a variable to compare it after I did some other changes but when I print after the second change, the value isn't the same.
My Example:

```
dict = {5:0,6:0}

def increase_values(dictionary):
    dict_to_return = dictionary
    dict_to_return[5] = 3
    return dict_to_return

dict_save = increase_values(dict)

print(dict_save)

dict[5] = 6

print(dict_save)

print(dict)
```

The first time I print dict_save the ouput will be `{5: 3, 6: 0}`
The second time I print dict save the Output will be `{5: 6, 6: 0}`
When I print dict the Output will be `{5: 6, 6: 0}`
and this is clear for me why but I don't know why the value of dict_save changed too.
I need the same value of dict_save after changing dict a second time.

Comment: `dict_to_return = dictionary` - this line makes both dicts point to the SAME dict. This is why you get 2 dicts changes. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html about creating a copy.

Comment: `dict_to_return = dictionary` creates another name for one dictionary. It doesn't make a copy. Try `dict_to_return = dictionary.copy()`

Comment: don't use `dict` as name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `dict` as a variable name because it is a keyword in python.

Second, when you do `dict_to_return = dictionary`, you are essentially having the same reference to the object, so when you modify 1, the other one gets modified also.

What you can do is, `dict_to_return = dictionary.copy()`, which will create a new dict.

Keep in mind that if your dict is big, that can get slow.

Have a look at [dict.copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: Are there more types which are just "referenced".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference this can answer your question

Answer (score 0):

The reason is when you do `dict_to_return = dictionary`, it points to same directory and does not make a copy of it. The below code will work for you as expected:

```
import copy
dict1 = {5:0,6:0}

def increase_values(dictionary):
    dict_to_return = dictionary
    dict_to_return[5] = 3
    return dict_to_return

dict_save = increase_values(copy.copy(dict1))
print(f'dict_save: {dict_save}')
dict1[5] = 6
print(f'dict_save: {dict_save}')
print(f'dict1: {dict1}')
```

Output:

```
dict_save: {5: 3, 6: 0}
dict_save: {5: 3, 6: 0}
dict1: {5: 6, 6: 0}
```