# How to create 2 separate dictionary from parent dictionary should not impact each other

Tags: python

I am trying to create 2 child dictionary from parent dictionary , but if performing any del operation it is impacting other child

**For example :**

**My parent dictionary is mentioned below**

`p : { 2:10 , 4:20 , 5:35 }`

**My child dictionary which is nothing but copy of main**

```
child_1 = p.copy()
child_2 = p.copy()
```

If I am performing any delete operation on `child_1`  then other `child_2` is getting impacted
It should not happen.

```
del  child_1[2]
```

It as deleted form child_2 as well that `key,value` of above

I want both should not be impacting each other if any del is performing

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Second dict is not getting impacted `child_1={4: 20, 5: 35}`, `child_2={2: [1, 2, 3], 4: 20, 5: 35}`

Comment: What does *p : { 2:10 , 4:20 , 5:35 }* represent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use deepcopy() instead of copy().

Explaination : copy() create a new object, but for mutable objects, it fill elements by creating references to parent's elements. deepcopy() will create a new object then recursively create copy of parent's elements.

Answer (score -1):

There is another question beforehand, that will help you.

You can use this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy).

I prefer:

```
import copy
dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1)
```

or

```
dict2 = dict(dict1)
```

or

```
dict2 = dict1.copy()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can loop over the parent dictionary's keys to copy it one-by-one:

```
child_1 = {}
child_2 = {}
for key in p.keys():
    child_1[key] = p[key]
    child_2[key] = p[key]
```