# after assigning a variable to a function. Why does the variable change every time the function is executed?

Tags: python, list, function, append, reinforcement-learning

when I assign a variable `X` to a function (`f`), its output is a list. variable `X` changes after every time that I execute my function `f` in everywhere in my project.

the project is about reinforcement learning. I have trouble with recording my states in the environment. when I append visited states to a list named `state_history` all appended states will be changing after each run of `environment` function and all states convert to the last state.
I write a pseudo code here so you can regenerate my problem.

```
# this function takes current state in dictionary format, increment it's value and returns next state 
def env_(current_state):

    nex_state=current_state['current state'] +1
    current_state['current state']=nex_state
   
    return current_state
# i run function 10 times 
state_history=[]
# initializing state
initial_state={}
initial_state['current state']=0
for i in range(10):
    nex_state=env_(initial_state)
    state_history.append(nex_state)
    initial_state=nex_state
print(state_history)
```

here is the result:
all appended states converted to the last state.

```
[{'current state': 10}, {'current state': 10}, {'current state': 10}, {'current state': 10}, {'current state': 10}, {'current state': 10}, {'current state': 10}, {'current state': 10}, {'current state': 10}, {'current state': 10}]
```

the expected result was:

```
[{'current state': 1}, {'current state': 2}, {'current state': 3}, {'current state': 4}, {'current state': 5}, {'current state': 6}, {'current state': 7}, {'current state': 8}, {'current state': 9}, {'current state': 10}]
```

Comment: `env_` takes an object `current_state`, modifies it, and return that object itself.  So every call to `env_` is operating on the single same dictionary.  Do you instead want to make a **copy** of `current_state`, modify that copy and return the copy?

Comment: @slothrop hi, yes.

Comment: @RaminBakthtiyari The answers here should put you on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy

Answer (score 0):

Here as next_State is changing everytime, when appending into the list, it changes with updated next_state instead of adding into the already created list, this is because, you are appending main list not the copy of it.
So try appending copy of next_state. Or you can go with extend() function instead of append.