# How to share nodes between graphs in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I want to share nodes(and their attributes) between two graphs. If one updates the attributes of nodes in one graph, they can be automatically updated in another graph. Is it possible?

Why I want to so:

In fact, I want two graphs with identical nodes but different edges. I can merge them into one multigraph and add tags to the edges recording which graph they belongs to. However, I think this will make my codes such like accessing neighborhood redundant.

Comment: can you provide minimal code to set up an example for the two graphs?

Comment: Are those graphs meant to be read-only?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco No, I expect that new nodes can be added and attributes can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes of node in the graph in networkx is just a `dict` object (generally speaking, it is a dict-like structure and can be customize by setting `node_attr_dict_factory`, see [the doc](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/graph.html)), and nodes are just keys inside `G._node`.

To share the nodes between graph, just let the nodes share the same attribute dicts. Do something like `dict2 = dict1`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45417247/9758790) for the difference between `dict.copy()` and `dict2 = dict1`. Note that the `Graph.copy` is using `dict.copy()` (see [source code](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/classes/graph.html#Graph.copy)).

I imitate the source code of [copy](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/classes/graph.html#Graph.copy) and [add_nodes_from](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/classes/digraph.html#DiGraph.add_nodes_from) and get the following workaround. One need to update the `_node` and add the key to the `_adj` attribute.

```
# share the node n in graph G with graph H
H._node[n] = G._node[n]
H._adj[n] = dict()
```

---

In addition, I want to find a solution specifically for when`H` **always** contains all nodes in `G`, I tried:

```
H._node = G._node
H._adj = {n: dict() for n in G._adj.keys()}
```

In this way, if one add nodes to G(or H), they can be automatically added to H(or G). However, one will still need to update the `H._adj`(or `G._adj`) manually.